# Unicode Processing in C++

Tags: c++, unicode

What is the best practice of Unicode processing in C++?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

- Use  [ICU](http://www.icu-project.org/) for dealing with your data (or a similar library)
- In your own data store, make sure everything is stored in the same encoding
- Make sure you are always using your unicode library for mundane tasks like string length, capitalization status, etc. Never use standard library builtins like `is_alpha` unless that is the definition you want.
- I can't say it enough: ***never iterate over the indices of a `string` if you care about correctness, always use your unicode library for this.***

Comment: Unless you are treating the `string` as binary data.

Answer (score 10):

If you don't care about backwards compatibility with previous C++ standards, the current C++11 standard has built in Unicode support: http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf

So the truly best practice for Unicode processing in C++ would be to use the built in facilities for it. That isn't always a possibility with older code bases though, with the standard being so new at present.

EDIT: To clarify, C++11 is Unicode aware in that it now has support for Unicode literals and Unicode strings. However, the standard library has only [limited support](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/codecvt/) for Unicode processing and conversion. For your current needs this may be enough. However, if you need to do a large amount of heavy lifting right now then you may still need to use something like [ICU](http://www.icu-project.org) for more in-depth processing. There are some proposals [currently in the works](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3398.html) to include more robust support for text conversion between different encodings. My guess (and hope) is that this will be part of the next [technical report](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1810.html).

Comment: That link to a draft standard doc isn't very helpful without a reference to a particular section that describes the "built in Unicode support" you're discussing.

Comment: @BenCollins


**Section 2.14.5 "String literals"** - discusses string literals, including string literals for UTF-8, UTF-16 and UTF-32 encodings.


**Section 22.4.1.4 "Class template codecvt"** - discusses the codecvt class used for converting between character encodings (including UTF-8, UTF-16 and UTF-32).


There is more about Unicode support peppered throughout the document, but these  seem to be the most critical sections on the subject.

Answer (score 8):

Our company (and others) use the open source [Internation Components for Unicode](http://www.icu-project.org/) (ICU) library originally developed by Taligent.

It handles strings, locales, conversions, date/times, collation, transformations, et. al.

Start with the  [ICU Userguide](http://www.icu-project.org/userguide/intro.html)

Answer (score 5):

Here is a checklist for Windows programming:

- All strings enclosed in _T("my string")
- strlen() etc. functions replaced with _tcslen() etc.
- Use LPTSTR and LPCTSTR instead of char * and const char *
- When starting new projects in Dev Studio, religiously make sure the Unicode option is selected in your project properties.
- For C++ strings, use std::wstring instead of std::string

Comment: Do not use "T" strings, chars and functions, unless you intend to do both Unicode and ANSI builds. If you only intend to do Unicode builds, just do regular wide character stuff:

L"my wide string"
wcslen(L"my string")

etc

Comment: Agree, only use _T macros if you want generic text, i.e., the ability to code for both Unicode and Ascii/MBCS.

Comment: In case you want do both Unicode and ANSI for C++ strings use something like
typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR> tString;

Comment: Ah yes, I always do #ifdef _UNICODE #define tstring std::wstring #else #define tstring std::string #endif but I like your way better Serge.

Comment: Honestly, I think that UTF16 is a waste, leaving all encodings in UTF8 is simpler and way more compatible with *nix.

Answer (score 3):

Look at
[Case insensitive string comparison in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11635/case-insensitive-string-comparison-in-c)

That question has a link to the Microsoft documentation on Unicode: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc194799.aspx

If you look on the left-hand navigation side on MSDN next to that article, you should find a lot of information pertaining to Unicode functions. It is part of a chapter on "Encoding Characters" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc194786.aspx)

It has the following subsections:

- The Code-Page Model
- Double-Byte Character Sets in Windows
- Unicode
- Compatibility Issues in Mixed Environments
- Unicode Data Conversion
- Migrating Windows-Based Programs to Unicode
- Summary

Answer (score 2):

Although this may not be best practice for everyone, you can write your own C++ UNICODE routines if you want!

I just finished doing it over a weekend. I learned a lot, though I don't guarantee it's 100% bug free, I did a lot of testing and it seems to work correctly.

My code is under the New BSD license and can be found here:

http://code.google.com/p/netwidecc/downloads/list

It is called WSUCONV and comes with a sample main() program that converts between UTF-8, UTF-16, and Standard ASCII. If you throw away the main code, you've got a nice library for reading / writing UNICODE.

Answer (score 1):

As has been said above a library is the best bet when using a large system.  However some times you do want to handle things your self (maybe because the library would use to many resources like on a micro controller).  In this case you want a simple library that you can copy the parts out of for the things you actually need.

Willow Schlanger's example code seems like a good one (see his answer for more details).

I also found another one that has smaller code, but lacks full error checking and only handles UTF-8 but was simpler to take parts out of.

Here's a list of the embedded libraries that seem decent.

#### Embedded libraries

- http://code.google.com/p/netwidecc/downloads/list (UTF8, UTF16LE, UTF16BE, UTF32)
- http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/unicode.html (UTF8)
- http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/ (Simple UTF8 library)

Answer (score 0):

Use IBM's [International Components for Unicode](http://www.icu-project.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the recommendations of [UTF-8 Everywhere](http://utf8everywhere.org/)