# How to obtain the width of string output?

Tags: c++, string

Consider

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{ 
    std::string test="αλφα";
    std::cout << "size() of '" << test << "' = " << test.size() << std::endl;
}
```

which produces

> size() of 'αλφα' = 8

How can I with the C++ standard library find the width of the output that will be produced by writing a string (i.e. 4 in the example above)?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/18850689/5470596 answers your question?

Comment: I'm not sure about the dup. OP might want a generic, not UTF-8-only answer.

Comment: Interesting reading http://utf8everywhere.org/#myth.strlen

Comment: @YSC Agreed, nothing useful in the standard library, so roll your own simple decoder. Only the OP can tell us if their code is unicode utf-8 or a specific MBCS, but I would recommend using utf-8 if you have a choice as it is "everywhere"

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is related to the *encoding* associated with the string.

This looks like UTF-8 encoding to me (the first character is **not** the lower case `'a'`). In that encoding, the characters you present take two bytes each which accounts for the answer.

UTF-8 encoding is broadly supported by the C++11 standard (rather elegantly UTF-8 doesn't have any zero bytes in any text stream *cf.* Windows Unicode) - you can use `std::string` although the lengths will, in general, be understated - but care must be taken when creating string literals of that type directly in your editor.

More reading from here: [How to use Unicode (UTF-8) in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993103/how-to-use-unicode-utf-8-in-c)

Comment: On windows, `std::wstring` can help. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402283/stdwstring-vs-stdstring

Comment: When you say it is "broadly supported" do you mean there is a wide range of support, or that C++ acknowledges it exits can can work with it (kind of)?

Comment: @YSC: Indeed it can, although I'd recommend, on balance, using UTF-8.

Comment: I think its' UTF-8 -- there is no lower case 'a', but two 'α' (greek alpha). Also, this is on a MAC, definitely no micro software.

Comment: I'm not sure why the UTF-8 representation for the string here would be 7 bytes large, as I only see small greek alpha characters, and no lower case 'a'. Here, I obtained: "αλφα" -> "ce b1 ce bb cf 86 ce b1"

Comment: @SirDarius: Oops yes you are correct, I've changed my opinion.

Comment: For the sake of comparing apples to apples, what Microsoft calls "Unicode" is either UTF-16 or UCS-2 depending on the age and quality of the software you're considering ;)

Comment: @Quentin: Either way it's full of damn NUL characters!