# Deprecated conversion from string literal to 'char*'

Tags: c++, string, char, deprecated, literals

I have a program which declares an array of strings like this:

```
char *colors[4] = {"red", "orange", "yellow", "blue"};
```

But I get the above compiler warning. It compiles but I'd rather use the non-deprecated way(if there is one). I've tried to find out what it means, but I can't seem to figure it out. I've heard using 'const' before 'char' works, but it would be helpful if someone could explain what the error means. Thanks.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

The strings that you enter: "red", "organge" etc are "literal", because they are defined inside the program code itself (they are not read directly from disk, user input /stdin etc.).

This means that if at any point you try to write to your `colors` you will be directly accessing your original input and thus editing it. This would cause some undesired run-time errors.

Declaring it as a const will make sure that you will never try to write to this pointer and such a run-time error can be avoided.

```
const char *colors[4] = {"red", "orange", "yellow", "blue"};
```

If you ever feel like editing these values at runtime, then you should copy the strings first.

Comment: The type signature needed will be `char const *colors[4]`, I believe (ie an array of four const pointers).

Comment: @JamesAylett , no, it is `const char *colors[4]`. Array of 4 pointers to const data.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Isn't it the same thing?

Comment: @szx, i think, he misspelled it: `an array of four constant pointers` is a `char * const colors[4]`. `char const *colors[4]` is a strange but valid way to describe an array of 4 pointers to const data.

Comment: 'const pointer to data' is not the same as pointer to const data. One is a pointer that may not be changed but its target (the data) may be. The other is a pointer that may be changed, but its target data is const and may not be changed. Discussion at [codeguru](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/general/article.php/c6967/Constant-Pointers-and-Pointers-to-Constants.htm). (Yeah, I know I'm a few years late but this is a frequent point of confusion).

Answer (score 11):

```
"red", "orange", "yellow", "blue"
```

these are constant string. Creating a non-const pointer to a constant string is wrong, hence the warning. At the moment you are getting a warning, but it should be an error since it is deprecated in c++03, and forbiden in c++11.

Answer (score 6):

These answers are all correct.

Note that if you have a function requiring an array of characters as an argument and you pass this argument like this:

```
foo ("bar");
```

the same warning will be shown. In this case, you can either :

1) Change it like this, as explained in the first answer:

```
void foo (char[] str) { printf(str); }

const char param[] = "bar";
foo (param);
```

2) Consider using a C++ standard string, like so:

```
void foo (std::string theParam) { std::cout << theParam; }

foo ("bar");
```

IMHO, as long as no real performance issue is concerned and you are not working with C libraries, or if you are building a C++ library for others to use, you should rather work with C++ immutable strings and their feature set.

If Unicode is a requirement, the support in C++ is "terrible" as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17103925/how-well-is-unicode-supported-in-c11).
[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55641/unicode-processing-in-c) gives you some clues (mainly: use IBM ICU library). If you already have Qt in your project, `QString` will also do the trick, and so will Gettext.

Comment: The function declaration `void foo (char[] str) { printf(str); }` is missing the const, it should be  `void foo (const char[] str) { printf(str); }` . The former will throw a `candidate function not
      viable: 1st argument ('const char *') would lose const qualifier` error.

Comment: I tried both of these approaches.  The compiler warned: `invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*'`.