# I cannot initializate WCHAR

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I need to make and WCHAR.
But it wont work, and i always get an error:

```
Error   C2440   'initializing': cannot convert from 'const wchar_t [11]' to 'WCHAR *'
 StateError (active)    E0144   a value of type "const wchar_t *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "WCHAR *
```

My code:

```
WCHAR *Testlooll = L"TEST";
```

Comment: Duplicate? Guys really? What have WCHAR* to do with TCHAR* (what is in your "ANSWER" duplicate) ?

Comment: For the record; *I* voted to close this as off-topic due to the lack of a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`L"TEST"` is a string literal of type `const wchar_t[5]`, which is an array of **const** characters (since the literal exists in read-only memory).  You are trying to initialize a `WCHAR*`, which is a pointer to a **non-const** character, to point at that array.

Initializing a pointer to **non-const** character data to point at an array of **const** character data is [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13690306/) in C++98 (to maintain backwards compatibility with legacy code), and is illegal in C++11 onwards.

You need to change the declaration of `Testlooll` according:

```
const WCHAR *Testlooll = L"TEST";
```

Or:

```
LPCWSTR Testlooll = L"TEST";
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Remy Lebeau's answer, if for some reason you can't modify the defination of Testlooll. You can just cast the const arry to a wchar_t*. For example,

```
struct someLibaryType
{
    WCHAR *Testlooll
};

someLibaryType a;
a.Testlooll = (wchar_t*)L"TEST";
```

Someone maybe argue should cast to WCHAR* just keep same with the defination type of Testlooll. But in this context, you've already used L to identify a string, so it has to be wchar_t*.