# How to initialize LPWSTR from a const string?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to initialize MENUITEMINFO for a call to InsertMenuItem. When trying to assign a const string to dwTypeData, I get an error. The code below is from MSDN samples.

I get an error for both types of assignment

```
mii.dwTypeData = "&Sample text";
mii.dwTypeData = L"&Sample text";
```

I am using Visual Studio 2019.

```
  MENUITEMINFO mii = { sizeof(mii) };
  mii.fMask = MIIM_STRING | MIIM_FTYPE | MIIM_ID | MIIM_STATE;
  mii.wID = idCmdFirst + IDM_DISPLAY;
  mii.fType = MFT_STRING;
  mii.dwTypeData = L"&Sample Text";
  mii.fState = MFS_ENABLED;
  if (!InsertMenuItem(hMenu, indexMenu, TRUE, &mii))
  {
    return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
  }
```

The error is 
Error (active)  E0144   a value of type "const wchar_t *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "wchar_t *"

According Microsoft documentation, the second one should work.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/working-with-strings

Edit: This is not solved by [I cannot initializate WCHAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52137990/i-cannot-initializate-wchar) because I cannot change the type as suggested in that answer.

Comment: The issue isn't the type of char, the issue is `const` and the poor Win32 API. In this case I think you'd be fine if you added a const cast. `mii.dwTypeData = const_cast<wchar_t*>(L"&Sample Text");`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I cannot initializate WCHAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52137990/i-cannot-initializate-wchar)

Comment: Yeah that article is wildly buggy, or at least out of date. String literals have had `const` on them for years now.

Comment: GSerg: Answer in that question is asking to change the declaration which I cannot.

Comment: source of this of course not vs2019 but */Zc:strictStrings* option (The */permissive-* compiler option implicitly sets this option and */permissive-* is on by default in vs2019 new project settings)

Comment: @RbMm Thanks. I pulled the source from a sample VS 2010 project and assumed some change to the defaults in VS 2019.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Some Windows structs are used to both "Get and Set" and string members in these structs point to mutable strings. This is in direct conflict with the compiler/linker settings that store strings literals in read-only memory.

It is theoretically unsafe to use a string literal with the setter function because it might write to the string (and then restore it back to its original content).

The only known place where this happens is the command line parameter in `CreateProcessW`.

In all other places you can probably just cast away const:

```
MENUITEMINFO mii = { sizeof(mii) };
mii.dwTypeData = const_cast<LPTSTR>(TEXT("&Sample Text"));
```

Comment: Modifying a string literal has undefined behaviour regardless of which molecules of your computer are used to store it

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes but the Visual C++ compiler used to default to putting string literals in read/write memory so people just ignored the issue.

Comment: simply all this api was designed much earlier /Zc:strictStrings option. by default string literals was in read only memory

Comment: @Anders Indeed, including the people who wrote the MSDN article. What I'm saying is that the warning/explanation in this answer needs to be stronger IMO. Currently it sounds like flipping some linker settings will solve the problem, but it won't: the string literals have the wrong types.

Comment: unfortunately old flaw of windows api. especially native api. for example big family of functions which got `POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES` as *in* parameter. despite it only in parameter and can be in const memory - it not declared as const pointer. but say `LsaOpenPolicy` (yet one known exception) by some reason require not const `OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES` pointer

Comment: @lig: No one is modifying the string literal, though. This is an artifact of the fact, that you cannot transitively convey `const`-ness of pointees in C or C++. Casting away `const` and passing a string literal is safe here. I'm not sure what warning should be more explicit or emphasized.

Comment: @IInspectable _"No-one is modifying the string literal"_ By stripping away the `const` you lose that guarantee (though I do agree that, in practice, in this particular example, and as explained by Anders, you're probably going to be alright) and the potential issues with this in general are only really touched on in this answer with respect to "compiler/linker settings that store strings in read-only memory", which completely sidesteps issues with _the language itself_ in order to focus solely on low-level implementation details. IMO Adrian covered the remaining quite nicely.

Comment: There's also a bit of terminology ambiguity with "strings" vs "string literals" and "const" vs "immutable" but I think we can forgive that

Comment: "The only known place where this happens is the command line parameter in CreateProcessW." is *exactly* the problem I'm having which led me to this old post :).

Answer (score 5):

Be careful! As **Lightness Races in Orbit** points out, modifying the data you pass could be a problem down the road. Try this, instead:

```
MENUITEMINFO mii = { sizeof(mii) };
mii.fMask = MIIM_STRING | MIIM_FTYPE | MIIM_ID | MIIM_STATE;
mii.wID = idCmdFirst + IDM_DISPLAY;
mii.fType = MFT_STRING;
wchar_t text[] = L"&Sample Text";
mii.dwTypeData = text;
mii.fState = MFS_ENABLED;
```

This way, you should be a wee bit safer - but not completely!! As **RbMm** points out, it is far better as a general rule to have the `dwTypeData` member pointing to a static character array. Somewhere (outside) the function …

```
static thread_local wchar_t menuText[MAXTEXTLEN];
```

Then, set up mii with …

```
wcscpy(menuText, L"&Sample Text");
mii.dwTypeData = menuText;
mii.cch = MAXTEXTLEN; // But not used in this case!
```

Comment: Thanks. I will keep this method in mind for user code. For this specific case I think Anders answer would suffice, I hope. Sorry, I can't up vote anything yet.

Comment: but nobody try modify *mii.dwTypeData* here. simply winapi was designed before */Zc:strictStrings* compiler option

Comment: @RbMm Absolutely agree **in this case**! But it's good practice to avoid passing string literals in structures like `MENUITEMINFO` as this can jump up and bite you on the behind, sometimes!

Comment: @Adrian - i can partial agree, if not performance penalty. in your example we need need allocate additional storage (usual in stack, because *text* will be usual local variable) and copy data from const literal to this temporary storage. also, not in this api of course, but from general view - some api can be asynchronous and require valid data until call not finished. in this case not posible use local variable and exit from function before api call end.

Comment: no, i not say that have **static** storage better. really if multiple threads in concurrent call your function with static storage - will be race and bug.

Comment: the `InsertMenuItem` is **synchronous** call - because this is full ok have temporary local buffer. simply from teoretical view, if we call asynchronous api - may be need more persistent storage, but not in this concrete case

Comment: so we have choise - or formal follow strict c++ rules and not pass const data to pointer declared not as const and not use *const_cast* but lost in efficient, or use *const_cast* if we sure that data will be not modified and used as const, despite not declared as const

Comment: @RbMm - Cool! See my edit to add `thread_local` after `static`. But there is not really a "right answer" here, it's down to the user/coder to choose what works best in each case. Using the WinAPI with strict, modern c++ will always present this sort of dilemma.

Comment: agree. i from self side prefer  `const_cast` because understand that this is safe with **concrete** case/api. use permanent storage really need only in rarely case ..  `static thread_local ` yet more overhead, when `InsertMenuItem` is exactly synchronous. so your first varian full ok here

Comment: more interesting case if want [`LVITEMW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/ns-commctrl-lvitemw) structure - *pszText is a pointer to a null-terminated string containing the item text. When responding to an LVN_GETDISPINFO notification, be sure that this pointer remains valid until after the next notification has been received.* but is only in case if we want change pointer of *pszText* to self string instead copy it to buffer

Comment: so if we have constant string literal and want assign it to *pszText* When responding to an LVN_GETDISPINFO notification , instead of copy it to *pszText* here more interesting choice.