# Creating array of character pointers and integer pointers

Tags: c++, c

```
char *x[4] = { "ffg", "fgf", "kkk" "mmm"};
int *x1[4] = { 1, 2 ,3 , 4};
```

If I create array of character pointers as mentioned above its compiling fine whereas if I create array of integer pointers as mentioned in second line I am getting the error

```
'initializing' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'int *'
```

How the syntax is working fine for characters but not working for integer. please explain anyone.

Comment: To add to the confusion, it will "work" if you use a different literal, namely zero, to initialize the array of integer pointers. That's because zero converts to a pointer, too. Did you actually _mean_ to have an array of integer pointers (i.e. what is it you intended to do)?

Comment: Um, your syntax isn't working fine for characters. The character version is `char *x[4] = { 'f', 'f', 'g' };`, and that has the same problem as the `int` version.

Answer (score 10):

`"ffg"` has type `char*` <sup>1</sup>, whereas `1` has type `int` (*not* `int*`). Hope you see the issue now.

<sup>1</sup>: Well, technically [it's `char[4]` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245664/string-literals-in-c), but that implicitly decays into `char*`. In C++ the type is `const char[4]` and you should [get a warning or an error from the compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650058/deprecated-conversion-from-string-literal-to-char).

Comment: I was connvinced `"ffg"` had type `const char[4]`

Comment: @juanchopanza: I was sure someone would jump in and correct, but you were super quick. :) Let me think how best to reword it without adding to the confusion.

Comment: using [1] for footnoting in a context where [] are being used for array access is unnecessarily confusing - put your note inline or just have a note without footnoting it.

Comment: *Technically* it's `const char [4]`, and this won't even compile under C++11.

Comment: @JohnDibling: That's the trouble with having questions tagged as both [c] and [c++]. Thanks for that edit BTW.

Answer (score 3):

`int *x1[4] = { 1, 2 ,3 , 4};` you can't do this , you're storing integers instead of integer pointers , to store integer pointers in your array here's how to procede :

```
int *x1[4] ;
int i , j , k , l;
x1[0] = &i;
x1[1] = &j;
x1[2] = &k;
x1[3] = &l;
```

Comment: @EricB there is no reason to believe the array is in a larger scope than the ints.

Answer (score 2):

`1, 2 ,3 , 4` are ints not pointers to `ints`. You might want to do. Casting like this:

```
int *x1[4] = { (int *)1, (int *)2 ,(int *)3 , (int *)4};
```

Will make the error go away but de-referencing will cause UB.

```
int i1=0, i2=0, i3=0, i4=0;
int *x1[4] = { &i1, &i2, &i3, &i4 };
```

A string literal (like `"ffg"`, `"fgf"`, etc) is kept in a read-only location (implementation dependent) and has type `char []`.

Since you tagged C++, you can try:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

int main()
{
    char arr [5] = "test";
    char *arr1 = "test";
    std::cout << typeid(arr).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid("test").name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid(arr1).name() << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
A5_c
A5_c
Pc
```

As you can see string literal decays to a pointer as said by NPE, although its type is of `char[5]`.

Comment: Whether string literals are stored in read only memory is implementation dependent.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong about an array of pointer.
I think you fail at understand what the compiler is telling you.

There is nothing wrong with the syntax. It is the semantic that is not good.

`{1, 2, 3, 4}` have type `int[4]` but you are assigning it to an `int*[4]` and that is not possible.

The error is an `initializing` error. It tell you that the parser is ok with your code but the semantic analyzer is not for the reason that an `int` is not the same as `int*`.