# When a function is possible to be given a char* or literal string, what is the right way to declare this function?

Tags: c++, xcode, clang, string-literals, gcc-warning

This question **is not** a duplicate of question:[deprecated-conversion-from-string-literal-to-char](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650058/deprecated-conversion-from-string-literal-to-char)

But yes I'm trying to get rid of this annoying Clang warning. In that Answer there are the following ways:

1. const_cast or (char*)
2. foo(char*) -> foo(const char*)

I also found some solution in [warning-deprecated-conversion-from-string-constant-to-'char'](http://blog.wolffmyren.com/2008/05/02/g-warning-deprecated-conversion-from-string-constant-to-%E2%80%98char%E2%80%99/)

3. strcpy
4. -Wno-write-string

My further question is :

1. How to set -Wno-write-string in Xcode? Or is there actually such a flag in Clang just as in gcc/g++? I didn't find it in [Clang Flag Ref](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html)
2. In my code, I get functions that are defined as foo(char*), they receive string or char* for some time, and receive literal string(e.g. "hello") for other time. For such kind of case, what is the right or proper way to decl/def foo?

Comment: Simple, take the parameter as `const char*`. And can't imagine why are you having second thougths.

Comment: @jrok why not `const std::string&`?

Comment: If your function is taking string literal as a possible parameter, that means it is not changing the string it self. So taking it as `const char*` makes sense.

Comment: @jrok sry but you miss the point, for some time the given param is char*, for other it is given literal. If I just simply change as `const char*`, then what about the exiting tens of use of `char*`

Comment: @rozina I have to admit that the original code I get have some design problem on this function. It may take both string literal and char* as possible param

Comment: @Ethan I don't see a problem [with that](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/837a8672b023ddf5).

Comment: @jrok i mean, consider this case: a constructor `foo(char*)`, and sometimes I use `foo("hello")`, sometimes I use `char init[]="hello"; foo(init)`

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Both ways work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just make your input parameter of your function a `const char*` and it will work. A function that has its input parameter as `const char*` means that the function will not make changes to what the pointer points to! So this means it will work with both string literlas (which are `const char*` themselves) and with regular `char*` parameters.

```
void printString(const char* str)
{
    printf("%s", str);
}
```

This function can be called like this:

```
int main()
{
    const char* pointerToLiteral = "string";
    char* str = new char[16];
    std::strcpy(str, pointerToLiteral );

    printString("true literal");
    printString(pointerToLiteral );
    printString(str);

    delete [] str;
}
```

When you pass a pointer to `printString` function it makes a copy of that pointer on its stack. And that copy is now of type `const char*`. Which means that the code of `printString` cannot change what the pointer points to. There is no reason this would not work if you pass a pointer of type `char*` to it.

Note that the other way around does not work. If we had `printString(char* str)`, you cannot pass it a `const char*` parameter, because now the function is saying that it can make changes to what the pointer points too, but the `const char*` parameter does not allow that!

Comment: 'literal' is not a literal, "literal" is

Comment: Thanks for your answer. A new case rises: `class foo{ foo(const char*); char* ptr;}`, `Foo(const char* ch){ ptr = ch }`. This gives out a warning

Comment: Change the member too :) `class foo{ foo(const char*); const char* ptr;};`