# Why having warning to implement arrays of pointer to string?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, gcc, string-literals

I am trying to implement an array of strings using pointer. Following is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
const int MAX = 4;
int main () {
char *names[] = {
  "abcd",
  "efgh",
  "ijkl",
  "mnop",
};
int i = 0;
for ( i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
  printf("Value of names[%d] = %s\n", i, names[i] );
}
return 0;
}
```

I am having a warning at the time of running it. Following is the warning:

```
C:\workspace>g++ test_pointer_string_arr.c -o tpsa.exe
test_pointer_string_arr.c: In function 'int main()':
test_pointer_string_arr.c:12:4: warning: deprecated conversion from string       const
ant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
};
^
test_pointer_string_arr.c:12:4: warning: deprecated conversion from string const
ant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
test_pointer_string_arr.c:12:4: warning: deprecated conversion from string const
ant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
test_pointer_string_arr.c:12:4: warning: deprecated conversion from string const
ant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
```

what is the problem?

Comment: I'm getting these warnings only if I try to compile the code with a C++ compiler. With a C compiler, no warnings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650058/deprecated-conversion-from-string-literal-to-char).

Comment: You use extension `.c` for your code, but compile with `g++` which normally is used to call C++ code only. For C you should call `gcc`. C and C++ are **different** languages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

String literals, in C are non-mutable. Any attempt to change the content of a string literal invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

By definition, strings have the type `char []`, so, by assigning a *string literal* to a `char *` does not *stop* you from writing a code that silently invokes UB.

Regarding the gcc option, `-Wwrite-strings`

> `-Wwrite-strings`
>
> When compiling C, give string constants the type `const char[length]` so that copying the address of one into a non-`const char *` pointer produces a warning. These warnings help you find at compile time code that can try to write into a string constant, but only if you have been very careful about using const in declarations and prototypes. Otherwise, it is just a nuisance. This is why we did not make `-Wall` request these warnings.

So, you need to write

```
 const char *names[] = {
  "abcd",
  "efgh",
  "ijkl",
  "mnop",
 };
```

and likewise.

As mentioned, most of the time, probably, it's not worthy.

Comment: "Strings" in C **never** have the type `char *`! And making string literals writeable is a bad idea and a violation of the standard.

Comment: @Olaf Removed that part to avoid misunderstanding, the type is obviously not a pointer but array. Thanks for pointing the issue in writing. :)

Comment: @Olaf if you're talking about `-Wwrite-strings`, that does not "make string literals writeable"

Comment: @M.M I think Olaf was trying to mention that not using `const` qualifier is violation of standard, in the sense that string literals must not be allowed to mutate, not even _by chance_.

Comment: @M.M: You are right, it is just a warning. Still some compilers support them for compatibility with pre-ANSI C.

Comment: @Olaf nobody suggested making string literals writable except you, and if a compiler does that then it is not a violation of the standard (because conforming code cannot make any such writes anyway)

Answer (score 2):

The code is perfectly valid in C. However, you apparently compile for a different language: C++. `g++` is the C++ frontend of the GNU Compiler Collection. While it might still use C mode due to the `.c` suffix, it enables other warnings.

As a general rule, you should use `gcc` to compile C code. In both languages writing to string literals is undefined behaviour (avoid under all circumstances). C is just less strict in enforcing [const-correctness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Const-correctness#Loopholes_to_const-correctness). That's why gcc has disabled this warning by default for C.

So, if you don't intend to change the strings in the array, you should always make the pointers to `const char`:

```
const char *names[] = ...
```

This helps the compiler detect illegal writes to the entries. You can also make the array itself `const`:

```
const char * const names[] = ...
```

That way you cannot change the entries. This is not only helpful for the compiler, but on some platforms (microcontroller) vital to store the data in non-modifyable memory.