# How to avoid c++ char* conversion error in jni

Tags: c++, java-native-interface

[image]

I have a problem with registering methods using JNI, if i want to use "method_name", compiler throws me error about that.

```
typedef struct {
    char *name;
    char *signature;
    void *fnPtr;
} JNINativeMethod;
```

How to type method name without crazy conversions like std::string -> const char* -> char*? Is it possible?

Main problem is that JNIMethod struct require char* not const char* that's why I'm asking

Comment: In C++ you can't initialize a `char*` with a string literal. You have to have `const char*`. See [Deprecated conversion from string literal to 'char*'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650058/deprecated-conversion-from-string-literal-to-char) or [Why is conversion from string constant to 'char*' valid in C but invalid in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20944784/why-is-conversion-from-string-constant-to-char-valid-in-c-but-invalid-in-c)

Comment: @JasonLiam: It _was_ deprecated in C++03, but the code in the picture is C++20. It's currently just plain illegal.

Comment: @MSalters Yup, it is invalid/illegal now. I was just mentioning the dupe. I've added some more dupes in the dupe list.

Comment: @JasonLiam but well how to use it in JNI struct with methods where char* is required not const char*

Comment: `std::strdup("bake")` ... but then what code is responsible for cleaning up that allocation?  Or just leak...?