# ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings] error shown in Visual Studio code while trying to run C code

Tags: c++, c, compiler-errors, string-literals, function-declaration

I am trying to run the following code which takes string parameter and returns the length of the string in characters in C language using Visual Studio Code, but I am getting:

Error message:

> ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*'
> [-Wwrite-strings]

Here is my code:

```
int str_length(char *mystring){

    int i=0;

    for(i=0; mystring[i]!='\0'; i++);

    return i;
}

void alpha(){

    printf("%d\n", str_length("-h=123"));

    printf("%d\n", str_length(""));

}
```

I am stuck with this task, maybe you could provide a possible solution or some parts of the code that I have to change?

Comment: In `c++` the compiler is correct. A string literal must be const since 2011 / c++11

Comment: If you are trying to do this in C, you should be using a C compiler.

Comment: Did you name the file with a .c extension? Was gcc used or g++?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is conversion from string constant to 'char\*' valid in C but invalid in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20944784/why-is-conversion-from-string-constant-to-char-valid-in-c-but-invalid-in-c) and [Deprecated conversion from string literal to 'char*'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650058/deprecated-conversion-from-string-literal-to-char)

Answer (score 2):

It means that you are compiling your program as a C++ program.

In C++ opposite to C string literals have types of constant character arrays.

From the C++ 17 Standard (5.13.5 String literals)

> 8 Ordinary string literals and UTF-8 string literals are also referred
> to as narrow string literals. **A narrow string literal has type
> “array of n const char”**, where n is the size of the string as
> defined below, and has static storage duration (6.7).

But even in C the function parameter shall have the qualifier `const` because the function does not change the passed string. The function can look the following way

```
size_t str_length( const char *mystring )
{
    size_t i = 0;

    while ( mystring[i] != '\0' ) i++;

    return i;
}
```

So within the function `alpha` you need to write

```
printf("%zu\n", str_length("-h=123"));

printf("%zu\n", str_length(""));
```

changing the conversion specifier from `%d` to `%zu`.  The signed type `int` can be not large enough to store the length of an arbitrary string.