# C++ How to get first letter of wstring

Tags: c++, wstring

This sounds like a simple problem, but C++ is making it difficult (for me at least): I have a wstring and I would like to get the first letter as a wchar_t object and then remove this first letter from the string.

This here does not work for non-ASCII characters:

```
wchar_t currentLetter = word.at(0);
```

Because it returns two characters (in a loop) for characters such as German Umlauts.

This here does not work, either:

```
wchar_t currentLetter = word.substr(0,1);

error: no viable conversion from 'std::basic_string<wchar_t>' to 'wchar_t'
```

And neither does this:

```
wchar_t currentLetter = word.substr(0,1).c_str();

error: cannot initialize a variable of type 'wchar_t' with an rvalue of type 'const wchar_t *'
```

Any other ideas?

Cheers,

Martin

---- Update -----
Here is some executable code that should demonstrate the problem. This program will loop over all letters and output them one by one:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    wstring word = L"für";
    wcout << word << endl;
    wcout << word.at(1) << " " << word[1] << " " << word.substr(1,1) << endl;

    wchar_t currentLetter;
    bool isLastLetter;

    do {
        isLastLetter = ( word.length() == 1 );
        currentLetter = word.at(0);
        wcout << L"Letter: " << currentLetter << endl;

        word = word.substr(1, word.length()); // remove first letter
    } while (word.length() > 0);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

However, the actual output I get is:

f?r
? ? ?
Letter: f
Letter: ?
Letter: r

The source file is encoded in UTF8 and the console's encoding is also set to UTF8.

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the first version? Can you post code for your Umlaut-problem?

Comment: C++ string functions are not inherently Unicode-aware. Don't expect them to know the difference between an umlaut and a letter.

Comment: `wstring::substr()` returns a new `wstring`, not a single character.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution provided by [Sehe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18324049/1508519):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/regex/pending/unicode_iterator.hpp>

using namespace std;

template <typename C>
std::string to_utf8(C const& in)
{
    std::string result;
    auto out = std::back_inserter(result);
    auto utf8out = boost::utf8_output_iterator<decltype(out)>(out);

    std::copy(begin(in), end(in), utf8out);
    return result;
}

int main() {
    wstring word = L"für";

    bool isLastLetter;

    do {
        isLastLetter = ( word.length() == 1 );
        auto currentLetter = to_utf8(word.substr(0, 1));
        cout << "Letter: " << currentLetter << endl;

        word = word.substr(1, word.length()); // remove first letter
    } while (word.length() > 0);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Output:

```
Letter: f

Letter: ü

Letter: r
```

Yes you need Boost, but it seems that you're going to need an external library anyway.

[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4359056/1508519)

> C++ has no idea of Unicode. Use an external library such as ICU
>   (UnicodeString class) or Qt (QString class), both support Unicode,
>   including UTF-8.

[2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12040593/1508519)

> Since UTF-8 has variable length, all kinds of indexing will do
>   indexing in code units, not codepoints. It is not possible to do
>   random access on codepoints in an UTF-8 sequence because of it's
>   variable length nature. If you want random access you need to use a
>   fixed length encoding, like UTF-32. For that you can use the U prefix
>   on strings.

[3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7469508/1508519)

> The C++ language standard has no notion of explicit encodings. It only
>   contains an opaque notion of a "system encoding", for which wchar_t is
>   a "sufficiently large" type.
>
> To convert from the opaque system encoding to an explicit external
>   encoding, you must use an external library. The library of choice
>   would be iconv() (from WCHAR_T to UTF-8), which is part of Posix and
>   available on many platforms, although on Windows the
>   WideCharToMultibyte functions is guaranteed to produce UTF8.
>
> C++11 adds new UTF8 literals in the form of std::string s = u8"Hello
>   World: \U0010FFFF";. Those are already in UTF8, but they cannot
>   interface with the opaque wstring other than through the way I
>   described.

[4 (about source files but still sorta relevant)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/331935/1508519)

> Encoding in C++ is quite a bit complicated. Here is my understanding
>   of it.
>
> Every implementation has to support characters from the basic source
>   character set. These include common characters listed in §2.2/1
>   (§2.3/1 in C++11). These characters should all fit into one char. In
>   addition implementations have to support a way to name other
>   characters using a way called universal character names and look like
>   \uffff or \Uffffffff and can be used to refer to unicode characters. A
>   subset of them are usable in identifiers (listed in Annex E).
>
> This is all nice, but the mapping from characters in the file, to
>   source characters (used at compile time) is implementation defined.
>   This constitutes the encoding used.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I would prefer a solution without dependencies on external libraries, though. I can't imagine that something as simple as this is not included in C++ "out of the box".

Comment: @marw Actually it's not that simple, and AFAIK (from the sources I quoted), the standard isn't really clear on this. If you want consistency, use a library.