# How do I display special characters in ncurses with Linux?

Tags: linux, ncurses

I'm trying to make a code where I make Lenny jump,  but lenny's face this: ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)

When compile & run the code (g++ -o Lenny main.cpp), I get the output "( ͡° �~\�~V ͡°)".  Is there a way I can get it to display ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)?

Comment: http://codepad.org/z6MnmwcD

Comment: @Predictability It's best to include the source code in your Stackoverflow posts. You could make a minimal complete program that prints just that one problematic line, it would have made the actual fix obvious.

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with Unicode characters. You can use this libray: [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/).

See more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55641/unicode-processing-in-c):

Comment: ICU is a bit overkill for something as simple as this.

Answer (score 0):

Linux has good Unicode support, you don't need any special libraries if all you're doing is output:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << "( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)\n";
}
```

online demo: http://ideone.com/UUS6Il

Or, you could not rely on Linux's built-in UTF-8 and be explicit about it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
int main()
{
    std::locale::global(std::locale("en_US.utf8"));
    std::wcout.imbue(std::locale());
    std::wcout << L"( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)\n";
}
```

online demo: http://ideone.com/EhTfB9

EDIT: Based on your code in the comment, your question is actually about the ncurses library I/O, not about C++. To get your program work as expected,

1. Add the line `setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.utf8");` near the beginning of your `main()` (and add `#include <clocale>` accordingly)
2. change your linkline to use `-lncursesw` as opposed to `-lncurses` if that's what you're using.