# c - get the number of symbols to be printed from a string

Tags: c, unicode

I need to find out how many symbols are to be printed from a string.
Let's say I have this code:

```
char    buf[200];

strcpy(buf, "\033[31m");     //Red color control sequence
strcat(buf, to_utf8(L'漢'));
strcat(buf, "a");
printf("%s", buf);
```

where

```
to_utf8(wchar_t c);
```

transforms the given white char into its utf8 representation and returns a string of it

Only 2 red symbol will be printed ("漢a").

If I were to run:

```
strlen(buf);
```

I would receive a length of 9

What I need is a function which will count the number of *to be printed* symbols, that is, in this case: 2

I need a solution without any external libraries.

Any ideas on this matter?

Comment: `wcslen()` is for `wchar_t`, otherwise it depends to enconding. `wchar_t` *is* an encoding to some extend.

Comment: "*I need a solution without any external libraries.*" <- which means to write one, and it must be aware of ANSI escape sequences and proper UTF8 multibyte characters. Quite some work.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Also it needs to be aware of Unicode combining characters, and who knows what other headaches. EmilTerman: Just use a library :) I [hear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55641/unicode-processing-in-c) ICU is good.

Comment: What gets printed depends entirely on the terminal.  Some may interpret the escape sequences and print `漢a` in red, while others won't and will print `\033[31m漢a`.  So you would need to know what the terminal is.

Comment: Or better, not use these sequences manually but **another library** instead (like, `curses`, e.g. in the `ncurses` implementation for \*nix)

Comment: How is "number of symbols" a useful data point?

Comment: If it needs to parse ESC [ sequences, I guess it also ought to parse CSI sequences in the same way for completeless, i.e. interpret the CSI character U+009B (which is encoded as \xc2\x9b in UTF-8) the same as the ESC [ sequence.

Comment: @melpomene I'm currently creating my own shell and I need to know exactly how many symbols are on the screen to know exactly where to place the cursor and do other stuff like that

Comment: If it's a shell for a terminal, with fixed-width fonts, you should also be aware that CJK characters are typically rendered at double the width of latin characters on such terminals.

Comment: @EmilTerman Then you need to know how many screen cells are occupied, not how many symbols there are. Some symbols have width 0, others have width 2.

Comment: @melpomene how do I find out how many cells are occupied then? Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: Isn't it the job of the terminal, not the shell, to know where the cursor is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone still has this question:

A solution to this problem was to know where my cursor is. This guy here has a nice piece of low level [code](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/get-cursor-position-in-c-947833/) which can read the cursor position.

This is not a direct answer to my question, but knowing where my cursor is, before and after I press a key, resolved my particular problem.