# Are there any ways to display my isbn code correctly?

Tags: c++

Here is an example from one of my data :

```
9789671539842,Zedeck Siew / Sharon Chin,Creatures of Near Kingdom,Vinlin Press Sdn Bhd,2018,1,24.00,2,2.
```

When I debug, the first data which is the isbn code will not be shown properly, for the first line, it would show 0, while for the rest of the lines, it would show numbers that were not from my text file, how can I fix that?

```
int file_reader()
{
    DATA d;
    ifstream infile("books.txt", ios::in);
    if (infile.is_open())
    {
        while (!infile.eof())
        {
            for (int row = 1; row < 42; row++)
            {
                cout << row << ". ";
                char line[200];
                infile.getline(line, 200, '\n');
                char* column;
                do
                {
                    column = strtok(line, ",");
                    d.isbn_code = atoi(column);
                    column = strtok(NULL, ",");
                    strcpy(d.author,column);
                    column = strtok(NULL, ",");
                    strcpy(d.title, column);
                    column = strtok(NULL, ",");
                    strcpy(d.publisher, column);
                    column = strtok(NULL, ",");
                    d.year_published = atoi(column);
                    column = strtok(NULL, ",");
                    d.quantity = atoi(column);
                    column = strtok(NULL, ",");
                    d.price = atof(column);
                    column = strtok(NULL, ",");
                    d.rack = atoi(column);
                    column = strtok(NULL, ",");
                    d.level_no = atoi(column);

                    cout << d.isbn_code << "," << d.author << "," << d.title << "," << d.publisher << "," << d.year_published << "," 
                        << d.quantity << "," << fixed << setprecision(2) << d.price << "," << d.rack << "," << d.level_no << endl;

                } while (column=="\0");
            } 
        } infile.close();
    }
    else
        cout << "File is not open\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the definition of `DATA`? What is the type of `DATA::isbn_code` data member?

Comment: sorry there was this typedef struct that i forgot to include 
```typedef struct
{
    int isbn_code, year_published, quantity, rack, level_no;
    char author[50], title[100], publisher[50];
    double price;
}DATA```

Comment: `9789671539842` overflows int capacity.

Comment: You don't need three loops.

Comment: I've changed it to ```char isbn_code [15]``` and now it can display correctly for the rest of the line except line 1 that shows a "∩╗┐" symbol and the very beginning of my isbn code. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: How do you mean by I don't need three loops?

Comment: Append conditions, `infile.is_open() && !infile.eof()`

Comment: These symbols are UTF8 BOM. Your file is UTF8 encoded. [Unicode Processing in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55641/unicode-processing-in-c)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong

Comment: Ok thanks everyone!