# Comparing wstring with ignoring the case

Tags: c++, string, unicode, stl

I am sure this would have been asked before but couldn't find it.  Is there any built in (i.e. either using std::wstring's methods or the algorithms) way to case insensitive  comparison  the two wstring objects?

Comment: Note, that case-insensitive comparisons are locale-dependent.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11635/case-insensitive-string-comparison-in-c , I'd recommend either the Boost solution or extracting c_str and using wcscasecmp/_wcsicmp

Comment: @Hasturkun: Thanks for the link. I vaguely remembered reading this on SO.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you don't mind being tied to Microsoft implementation you can use this function defined in `<string.h>`

```
int _wcsnicmp(
   const wchar_t *string1,
   const wchar_t *string2,
   size_t count 
);
```

But if you want best performance/compatibility/functionality ratio you will probably have to look at boost library (part of it is stl anyway). Simple example (taken from [different answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11635/case-insensitive-string-comparison-in-c/315463#315463) to different question):

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

std::wstring wstr1 = L"hello, world!";
std::wstring wstr2 = L"HELLO, WORLD!";

if (boost::iequals(wstr1, wstr2))
{
    // Strings are identical
}
```

Comment: The L encoding-prefix is missing from the string literals

Answer (score 6):

Using the standard library:

```
bool comparei(wstring stringA , wstring stringB)
{
    transform(stringA.begin(), stringA.end(), stringA.begin(), toupper);
    transform(stringB.begin(), stringB.end(), stringB.begin(), toupper);

    return (stringA == stringB);
}

wstring stringA = "foo";
wstring stringB = "FOO";
if(comparei(stringA , stringB))
{
    // strings match
}
```

Comment: that if(stringA == stringB) forces me to leave a comment! :) 

should be return (stringA == stringB)

Comment: This solution will not work in several locales, in some languages when you convert to uppercase and then back you get different strings.

Comment: You didn't just compare the strings, you have actually made both strings UPPERCASE regardless of the outcome. Try writing a method with the signature `bool compare(const wstring stringA, const wstring stringB)`, then fix this algorithm.

Comment: Should have used towupper.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `std::tolower()` to convert the strings to lowercase or use the function `wcscasecmp` to do a case insensitive compare on the `c_str()`'s.

Here is a comparison functor you can use directly as well:

```
struct ci_less_w
{
  bool operator() (const std::wstring & s1, const std::wstring & s2) const
  {
      #ifndef _WIN32
            return wcscasecmp(s1.c_str(), s2.c_str()) < 0;
      #else
            return _wcsicmp(s1.c_str(), s2.c_str()) < 0;
      #endif
  }
};
```

Comment: I think a Standard Library solution was asked for.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the boost string algorithms library. Its a header only library as long as you're not going to do regex. So you can do that very easily.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/string_algo.html

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>


 bool icase_wchar_cmp(wchar_t a, wchar_t b)
{
  return std::toupper(a) == std::toupper(b);
}


bool icase_cmp(std::wstring const& s1, std::wstring const& s2)
{
  return (s1.size() == s2.size()) &&
             std::equal(s1.begin(), s1.end(), s2.begin(),
                              icase_wchar_cmp);
}



int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  using namespace std;

  wstring str1(L"Hello"), str2(L"hello");

  wprintf(L"%S and %S are %S\n", str1.c_str(), str2.c_str(),
              icase_cmp(str1,str2) ? L"equal" : L"not equal");

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Talking about English right ?! though I would go with my lovely Boost :)

```
bool isequal(const std::wstring& first, const std::wstring& second)
{
    if(first.size() != second.size())
        return false;

    for(std::wstring::size_type i = 0; i < first.size(); i++)
    {
        if(first[i] != second[i] && first[i] != (second[i] ^ 32))
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: +1. (second[i] ^ 32) is interesting. I never knew this was how ascii was designed!

Comment: This will consider `[` to be the same as `{`, and `*` to be the same as a newline, along with many other such inaccuracies. Besides, assuming English when dealing with wide strings is almost certainly wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you need that the string will always make case insensitive comparation (when using operators == or !=), then a possible elegant solution is to redefine char_traits::compare method.

Define your own structure. Example

```
struct my_wchar_traits: public std::char_traits< wchar_t>
{
    static int compare( const char_type* op1, const char_type* op2, std::size_t num) 
    {
       // Implementation here... any of the previous responses might help...
    } 
};
```

Then, define your own case insensitive string:

```
typedef std::basic_string< wchar_t, my_wchar_traits> my_wstring;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use mismatch() or lexicographical_compare(). This is suggested by Scott Meyers in Effecitve STL, item 35.

Comment: Example for those of us that do not have that book would be nice.

Comment: Note that neither of these functions will compare case-insensitively by default.  You would still have to write a function that compares characters case-insensitively and pass it to those functions.