# g++ error: ‘stricmp’ was not declared in this scope (but OK for 'strcmp')

Tags: c++, g++

I am trying to compile the following very very simple piece of source code:

```
#include <cstring>
// #include <string.h>
// using namespace std;

class Helper {
public:
    int cStringsAreEqual(const char *s1, const char *s2) {
        return stricmp(s1, s2);
    }
};
```

... but I am getting the following error message:

```
   g++ error: ‘stricmp’ was not declared in this scope
```

However when I use **strcmp()** instead of **stricmp()** then everything is fine!

What can be wrong here? Shouldn't stricmp() be allowed when strcmp() is allowed?

Sureley, this all could be written in a much better way without using strcmp/stricmp.

But that's not the point here.

I am porting a piece of software - which makes much use of calls to stricmp(). And if somehow possible I would like to avoid all of the efforts needed to change every call to stricmp.

Any help on this would be very much appreciated!

BTW: I am using Ubuntu karmic OS (v9.10) with g++ v4.4.1.

BTW: as you can see I also made some trials with '#include string.h' or with 'namespace std' but nothing helped.

Comment: Considering that stricmp and strcmp are not the same (the latter is case sensitive), you might want to hesistate before changing them anyhow.

Comment: I *know* that they are not the same. That's why I want to use stricmp and not strcmp

Comment: Note also that `<string.h>` and `<cstring>` aren't exactly the some.  It's not the cause of your problem, but you'll need to write `std::strcmp` (or `std::strcoll`) rather than assuming the names are imported into the global namespace.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Try `strcasecmp()`. Here's the [manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcasecmp) for it. It is conforming to 4.4BSD and POSIX.1-2001.

Comment: That would be an option. strcasecmp() seems to have the same parameters. So it shouldn't be to difficult to create a small perl script that does a global change. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem. Also take a look at Mark Rushakoff's comment on how the  locale settings affect this function.

Comment: Beware that strcasecmp depends on your locale. Thus strcasecmp("div","DIV") will NOT return 0 in a turkish locale (lowercase I is ı). That means it matters where your string comes from :-(. There are other examples in other languages. You might break your program for foreign users.

Answer (score 14):

[`stricmp` is neither POSIX nor ANSI](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/libc/libc_761.html), so it doesn't really matter if `strcmp` is allowed, if your compiler or standard library is strictly adhering to POSIX or ANSI standard library functions (as is probably the case with the GCC suite).

Comment: It's complicated, because the idea of "case-sensitivity" can depend on your locale or OS.  See some of the answers in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11635/case-insensitive-string-comparison-in-c

Comment: I am using Eclipse CDT on windows 7 with Cygwin, and stricmp is accepted there. On my Linux machine, with GCC it is not acepted. Does that means that compiler included with Cygwin IS NOT POSIX or ANSI?

Answer (score 13):

Add a define for it to overwrite stricmp with strcasecmp on the platforms you are looking for.

```
#ifdef _IPHONE <- your platform define here
#define stricmp strcasecmp
#define strnicmp strncasecmp
#endif
```

Then you can just use stricmp always.

Comment: where do we put this though

Comment: Just put it in a header or at the top with any other preprocessor directives (ifdefs/defines): http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/  #define _IPHONE would switch to the usage above minus the "<- .. " part"

Answer (score 0):

If you've got Boost, use `boost::algorithm::iequals(s1, s2, std::locale::classic())` in `<boost/algorithm/string/predicate.hpp>` (or leave off locale if you want locale-sensitivity). It works with C strings, `std::[w]string`, `vector<char>`, etc.

Answer (score -2):

Pretty easy to make your own if need be...

```
int my_stricmp (const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    while (*s1 != 0 && *s2 != 0)
    {
        if (*s1 != *s2 && ::toupper (*s1) != ::toupper(*s2))
        {
            return -1;
        }
        s1++;
        s2++;
    }
    return (*s1 == 0 && *s2 == 0) ? 0 : -1;
}
```

Comment: How does this return a positive value when `s1` sorts later than `s2`?  Or is it intended to have a different interface to `std::strcmp()`?

Comment: Addressed issue @TobySpeight pointed out.  Also corrected if logic.

Comment: `CAVEAT`: The calls to `::toupper` are locale specific.  You may get different results depending on where you run this.  Consider using the locale aware overrides instead.

Comment: @Jesse, your proposed change was quite substantial, and so was rejected by the reviewers.  You might want to add some explanation and turn it into a proper answer instead.

Comment: @Toby: reviewers be damned. If you have posted an incorrect answer, you should either fix it (yourself if need be), or delete it, or at least flag it prominently as incorrect.