# The following code always give 'draw!' as output

Tags: c++

I don't understand why the following code always prints 'draw!'. Can you help me figure that out?

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void main()

{
    clrscr();

    int choice1;
    char choice2[50];
    int compare(const char*, const char*); //prototype
    char s[100];
    cout << "\n\n WELCOME TO STONE PAPER SCISSORS " << endl
         << endl;
    cout << " enter your choice" << endl;

    cout << "\n 1:SCISSORS \n";
    cout << "\n 2:ROCK \n";
    cout << "\n 3:PAPER \n";
    cout << "enter choice number";
    cin >> choice1;

    if (choice1 == 2) {
        cout << "you have entered Stone!";
        strcpy(s, "ROCK");
    }
    if (choice1 == 1) {
        cout << "you have entered scissors";
        strcpy(s, "SCISSORS");
    }
    if (choice1 == 3) {
        strcpy(s, "PAPER");
        cout << "you have entered paper";
    }
    randomize();
    float point = 2;
    float compchoice;
    compchoice = random(point);

    if (compchoice < 0.37) {
        strcpy(choice2, "ROCK");
    }
    else if (compchoice < 0.64) {
        strcpy(choice2, "PAPER");
    }
    else {
        strcpy(choice2, "SCISSORS");
    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << "User Choice=" << s << endl;
    cout << "Computer Choice=" << choice2 << endl;
    cout << s << "\t"
         << "VS"
         << "\t" << choice2 << "="
         << " ";

    int p = compare(s, choice2);
    if (p == 1) {
        cout << "computer wins";
        if (p == 0)
            cout << "user wins";
        if (p == -1)
            cout << "draw!";

        getch();
    }
    int compare(const char* s, const char* choice2)
    {
        if (s == "SCISSORS") {
            if (choice2 == "ROCK")
                return 1;
            else
                return 0;
        }
        else if (s == "ROCK") {
            if (choice2 == "SCISSORS")

                return 0;
            else
                return 1;
        }
        else if (s == "PAPER") {
            if (choice2 == "SCISSORS")
                return 1;
            else
                return 0;
        }
        else
            return -1;
    }
```

Comment: Link ain't working, please read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: the link is updated now..

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] *in the question itself*.

Comment: the link is updated

Comment: Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time.

Comment: code too long for comment

Comment: Then don't post the whole code, post only the part that's relevant.

Comment: pls click the link for the code.. it is updated!

Comment: @RåhülRàvi You are using char[] instead of std::string, so you end up comparing pointers instead of strings.

Comment: Put the code in the question. Remember that stack overflow is not a forum. The main point of a question is to help future readers with the same problem. If you post to an external site the link may not work in a month and that will help no one.

Comment: thank you @jv! for your adice

Comment: I moved the code to this site. It seems to be missing a `}` before your definition of `int compare(const char* s, const char* choice2)`

Comment: @drescherjm, I was trying the same thing, thanks for being faster!

Comment: I used `http://format.krzaq.cc/` to fix the c++ code formatting. Then copied it back and edited the question.

Answer (score 3):

The problem in this code lies within code like `if (choice2 == "SCISSORS")`
as this is a pointer comparison. For details, see [this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330350/c-or-c-how-to-compare-two-strings-given-char-pointers).

I would suggest modernizing this code and use `std::string` instead of `char [50]` as you have to worry less about memory for these strings, nor the fact that strings are stored as arrays.