# Build error while using stricmp in Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am getting build error while using stricmp to compare two C strings in Xcode.

Error : Implicit declaration of stricmp invalid in C99. What is it means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What it means is that a declaration of stricmp cannot be found in the headers you have included. Earlier versions of C allowed you to call functions that were not declared in the headers and assumed that they were declared as `int function()`

stricmp is not in the C or POSIX standards. For iOS look at [`strcasecmp()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/system/conceptual/manpages_iphoneos/man3/strcasecmp.3.html) as per this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784767/g-error-stricmp-was-not-declared-in-this-scope-but-ok-for-strcmp)

Comment: For further reference, the correct function is `strcasecmp()` and it's in `strings.h` http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/system/conceptual/manpages_iphoneos/man3/strcasecmp.3.html