# c++ std::string to boolean

Tags: c++

I am currently reading from an ini file with a key/value pair.  i.e.

```
isValid = true
```

When get the key/value pair I need to convert a string of 'true' to a bool.  Without using boost what would be the best way to do this?

I know I can so a string compare on the value (`"true"`, `"false"`) but I would like to do the conversion without having the string in the ini file be case sensitive.

Thanks

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Another solution would be to use `tolower()` to get a lower-case version of the string and then compare or use string-streams:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>

bool to_bool(std::string str) {
    std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), ::tolower);
    std::istringstream is(str);
    bool b;
    is >> std::boolalpha >> b;
    return b;
}

// ...
bool b = to_bool("tRuE");
```

Comment: +1 nice answer + another 1 cos I did not know about boolalpha. Note that boost::lexical_cast (which does the same) is not very forgiving about case either

Comment: this is really cool... I was not previously aware of `std::boolalpha`

Comment: I tried to use this but its saying that transform isnt part of std.  I included <iostream>  What did I miss?

Comment: @Wesley: `#include <algorithm>`.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <string>
#include <strings.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

bool
string2bool (const std::string & v)
{
    return !v.empty () &&
        (strcasecmp (v.c_str (), "true") == 0 ||
         atoi (v.c_str ()) != 0);
}

int
main ()
{
    std::string s;
    std::cout << "Please enter string: " << std::flush;
    std::cin >> s;
    std::cout << "This is " << (string2bool (s) ? "true" : "false") << std::endl;
}
```

An example input and output:

```
$ ./test 
Please enter string: 0
This is false
$ ./test 
Please enter string: 1
This is true
$ ./test 
Please enter string: 3
This is true
$ ./test 
Please enter string: TRuE
This is true
$
```

Comment: `strcasecmp` is non-portable. Some platforms use `stricmp`, strangely.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use boost, try `strcasecmp`:

```
#include <cstring>

std::string value = "TrUe";

bool isTrue = (strcasecmp("true",value.c_str()) == 0);
```

Comment: `strcasecmp` doesn't exist under Windows.

Comment: Oh, come on! It sounds like a Boost is the only way to go to compare strings :-) There are much more easiest and efficient ways then doing lexical cast, really. Especially when you know exactly what you are doing and not creating an all-purpose-all-in-one conversion library.

Comment: @zneak - Windows has "stricmp" though (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k59z8dwe%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: strcmpi is POSIX standard, with the silly deprecation but still working behavior in Visual Studio.

Comment: `stricmp` is more widely used for case insensitive compare of C-style strings.

Answer (score 0):

Lowercase the string by iterating the string and calling `tolower` on the carachters, then compare it to `"true"` or `"false"`, if casing is your only concern.

```
for (std::string::iterator iter = myString.begin(); iter != myString.end(); iter++)
    *iter = tolower(*iter);
```

Comment: tolower() works on a single character, c_str() returns a pointer to a string that must not be modified.
So this idea would actually be harmful.

Comment: @Uli Schlanchter Where the hell did I get the idea it worked on strings? Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions for case-insenstive string comparisions on C++ strings can be found here:
[Case insensitive string comparison in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11635/case-insensitive-string-comparison-in-c)