# Exception with cast using boost library

Tags: c++, boost, casting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I use boost::lexical_cast and std::boolalpha? i.e. boost::lexical_cast< bool >(“true”)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452136/how-do-i-use-boostlexical-cast-and-stdboolalpha-i-e-boostlexical-cast-b)

I am trying to cast from string to bool with the method lexical_cast as I show below:

```
boost::lexical_cast<bool>("false");
```

The problems is that it throws the exception

```
boost::bad_lexical_cast
```

I have read the documentation and I understand that `boost::lexical_cast<bool>("false")` is correct.

Comment: "I understand that ... is correct"? The documentation doesn't say that. In fact there was [a discussion in the boost community](http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2002/05/30074.php) some time ago about this issue, and they ended up accepting that there is no simple 'correct' way to design this.

Comment: Ok, thanks very much but my englesh is really bad and i dind´t understand, Sorry