# How to set the value of a boolean to the desired state

Tags: c++, boolean

I want to include a function in my class to set the value of a boolean to the desired state. However, I am not sure about the syntax, especially because I do not know what type "true/false" is.

I was thinking about something similar to:

```
void setBool(boolean bBool, string str){
    bBool = str;
}

int main (){
    bool myBool;
    string str = "false";
    setBool (myBool, str);
    return 0;
}
```

Does anybody have any ideas? What datatype would "true/false" be?

Comment: Just use `bBool = true;` or `bBool = false;` to set its value.

Comment: true/false or 1/0 is `boolean`

Comment: If you want to parse the string there to a bool take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3613424/874508

Comment: There's a handy [manipulator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/boolalpha) that will handle it for you already.

Comment: Thanks @ScottMcGready that's what I needed, I can define my function as setBool(bool, bool) and call it as setBool(myBool, true); true/false is considered a boolean itself.

Answer (score 1):

`bool`'s are a type of integer datatype that represents true or false.  They do this by the number they hold.  A zero value is false and all other values are true.  `true` and `false` themselves [are actually keywords](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword).  If you want to convert the string into a bool then you can do it like

```
void setBool(bool& bBool, const string& str)
{
    if (str == "false")
        bBool = false;
    else
        bBool = true;
}
```

You could also store the result of a comparison in a bool as a comparison returns a bool.  So if we do:

```
bBool = (str != "false");
```

Then if `str` is not equal to `"false"` then that will be `true` and `bBool` will be `true` otherwise it will be set to false.  So no the function would be:

```
void setBool(bool& bBool, const string& str)
{
    bBool = (str != "false");
}
```