# Equality Test Operator in String Classes

Tags: c++, std

I noticed that many string classes in C++ doesn't implement the `==` operator to compare to strings. What is the reason behind that? As far as I can see, implementing a class for a string is supposed to make the string an entity by itself, rather than a pointer to a set of characters. So we should definitely expect the `==` operator to be implemented to compare the values of two entities (i.e. strings)!

Comment: Can you give an example of any that don't?  std::string does for example.

Comment: Hmmm... are you sure about std::string?! I just checked the implementation of std::string (MSVC implementation) and it doesn't contain any implementation for `==`.

Comment: I thought the main reason for not implementing it is avoid overriding the default behaviour of `==`, which is supposed to compare the very low level of the values, rather than what they represent (i.e. pointer vs. content).

Comment: See http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/basic_string.html.  std::string absolutely, definitely implements ==.

Comment: the comparison operators for `std::string` are here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/operators/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often, when a class doesn't implement `operator==`, it's because there's a free function outside the class. The advatnage of a free function `operator==` is that it supports implicit conversions on both sides. This is especially important for strings, because there you often use `const char[]` literals and want that implicit conversion. E.g.

```
MyString S("Hello");
if ("hello" == S) { // Can't use MyString::operator== here
  std::cout << S;
}
```

Comment: I believe this is the best answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

std::string is basic_string and it does have operator==, which uses the compare method of char_traits.

You can even put in a specialist traits class of your own to do case-insensitive comparison.

Answer (score 1):

A reason for not implementing operator== for a string class would be if you believe that there are more ways to compare strings: case sensitive/insensitive, ignore accents,... and you provide different compare functions to let the user specify.

It is still a choice and as Jeff Foster already commented: it is implemented in the only real string in C++ (std::string)

Comment: That is why it delegates to the traits class to do the compare. You can get case-insensitive compare by using a traits class that compares that way.

Comment: @CashCow: any links for that?  Anyway, I was showing a design choice when implementing yet another string.

Comment: here on stack overflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11635/case-insensitive-string-comparison-in-c