# C++ count and map

Tags: c++, count

I am counting the number of times every word occurs in a text file. I would like to avoid cases and hence am doing tolower to my input and then counting. I have a map data structure having string and int to keep count. Now, when I output the word and its count, I don't want the word to be in lower case, but want it to maintain its original case. So, for counting all the words should change to lowercase but while giving output they all should be in their original case. Is there anyway to achieve this with using only one map?

Comment: What should happen if the same word occurs both in lower and upper case in the text. Do you want to record all occurences or just the first one or last one?

Comment: If you have two words that are the same except the casing, will you output it as two different words with one as count, or as one word with two counts?

Comment: I would output it as one word with two counts

Comment: Can you give an example of how you want the output to be in case you have the following as your input "hello HELLO Hello".

Comment: In that case I don't really see a reason you want to keep the casing. Or do you want to output the word, the count and then the list of all words? Otherwise how would you select which of the different casings of the word you should print?

Comment: Let me give more elaborated example output: "hello HELLO Hello World" should give: hello 3   World 1  (note the case of World is maintained)

Comment: currently what is happening is: "hello HELLO Hello World" gives:  hello 3 world 1 (note case changed, as I do tolower to all char)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The third template parameter of `std::map` is a comparator type. You can provide your own comparison operation, in your case a case-insensitive one.

```
struct CaseInsensitive {
  bool operator()(std::string const& left, std::string const& right) const {
    size_t const size = std::min(left.size(), right.size());

    for (size_t i = 0; i != size; ++i) {
      char const lowerLeft = std::tolower(left[i]);
      char const lowerRight = std::tolower(right[i]);

      if (lowerLeft < lowerRight) { return true; }
      if (lowerLeft > lowerRight) { return false; }

      // if equal? continue!
    }

    // same prefix? then we compare the length
    return left.size() < right.size();
  }
};
```

Then instanciate your map:

```
typedef std::map<std::string, unsigned, CaseInsensitive> MyWordCountingMap;
```

Note: only the first spelling is preserved (which seems okay with you)

Comment: bool operator()(std::string const& left, std::string const& right) const   Is this line doing operator overloading?

Comment: @user1035927: Not really. It is declaring the operator `bool CaseInsensitive::operator()(...) const`, functors usually declare an `operator()` something, and in particular for maps, the functor need an operator that compares two keys and return a boolean. Generally speaking, operator overloading concerns the free-function at namespace level: `operator+`, `operator*`, `operator<`, ...

Comment: sorry to bother you, one more query, why do we have the operator declared as const? any specific reason for that

Comment: @user1035927: The `operator` here is a regular method of `CaseInsensitive` (indeed you could invoke it as `CaseInsensitive ci; ci.operator(left, right);`. Since it does not modify the state of `CaseInsensitive`, it is declared `const` to document this fact. As there is no state, it does not matter much, but I am a const evangelist :)

Answer (score 3):

This should work. For multiple cases the first case will be inside the map and not lower case. Also the solution uses only one map as you wanted

```
using namespace std;

struct StrCaseInsensitive
{
    bool operator() (const string& left , const string& right )
    {
        return _stricmp( left.c_str() , right.c_str() ) < 0;
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    char* input[] = { "Foo" , "bar" , "Bar" , "FOO" };
    std::map<string, int , StrCaseInsensitive> CountMap;

    for( int i = 0 ; i < 4; ++i )
    {
        CountMap[ input[i] ] += 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map<string, vector<string> >`.

The key is the lowercase word. The value is the vector of all the given cases of this word.

(you can also use `multimap<string, string>` which is basically the same, but I usually prefer  a map of vectors)

```
 map<string, vector<string> > m;
 m.size(); // number of lowercase words
 m["abc"].size(); // number of the given cases of the word "abc"
```

Comment: I would use a `list` instead of a `vector` in this case.

Comment: Because the number of words to put in the vector is not known, which may cause lots of reallocations of the vector as words are added.

Comment: A list will require the same reallocations. A list is usually useful only when you have to add elements in the beginning or in the middle of the container, but this is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to happen with different case variants of the same word?

One possibility is to use [std::multiset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/multiset/) with a [caseless comparator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11635/case-insensitive-string-comparison-in-c) as its `Compare` template parameter. In this case, all variants of each word will be preserved in the set. Number of occurrences of each word can be obtained via [count()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/multiset/count/) member function of the set.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a structure or `std::pair` to keep both the original case and a number of occurrences. Your type would then look like this: `map < string, pair <string, int> >`

Comment: If I decide to use map<string, string, int>, where int holds the count, and one string holds the lowercase and other the original case, will this be an elegant solution

Comment: `map` is declared like this: `template < class Key, class T, class Compare = less<Key>, class Allocator = allocator<pair<const Key,T> > > class map;`, it does have three template arguments, but the third is comparator, not value type. The `map` only represents key-value pairs, and if you want to supply some additional data, you will have to make value compound somehow. If I were you, however, I'd just create a second `map <string, string>` to hold original casing for every item. IMHO it adds less complexity than structures or pairs.

Comment: Scratch that, @Matthiew's solution is much better.