# c++ case insensitive count in C++

Tags: c++, case-insensitive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Case insensitive string comparison in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11635/case-insensitive-string-comparison-in-c)
>   [C++ count and map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061317/c-count-and-map)

How to do case insensitive count in C++ without using `tolower`. I want to count words irrespective of their case, but do not want to use `tolower`. Any other solution in C++?

Comment: If you do not use `tolower`, then you will probably have to implement some equivalent function yourself. Why this restriction?

Comment: Didn't you just asked it?! "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061317/c-count-and-map"

Comment: And [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291476/case-insensitive-stdset-of-strings/4291497#4291497) may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use as std::map with a custom comparer function object that is case insensitive

```
struct StrCaseInsensitive
{
    bool operator() (const string& left , const string& right )
    {
        return _stricmp( left.c_str() , right.c_str() ) < 0;
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    char* input[] = { "Foo" , "bar" , "Bar" , "FOO" };
    std::map<string, int , StrCaseInsensitive> CountMap;

    for( int i = 0 ; i < 4; ++i )
    {
        CountMap[ input[i] ] += 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think the question is about implementing that comparer function you speak of...

Comment: I was editing the post with an example

Comment: Why not just write the function the first time around?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use `tolower`, there's always `toupper`, which works just as well.

You don't have to *store* the string in lowercase, you can just *compare* in lowercase.

Or you can use [strcasecmp](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strcasecmp.html) or [stricmp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235365(v=vs.80).aspx) if it's available.

Or you can use [someone else's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11635/case-insensitive-string-comparison-in-c).