# Sorting strings in Vector algorithm not working

Tags: c++, function, sorting

I have a vector of struct items that has a string inside. I am trying to sort the vector of items  by having the string inside the items in alphabetical order... so far I have:

```
vector<Item> sorter;

std::sort(sorter.begin(), sorter.end(), SortHelp);

//predcate function
bool SortHelp(Item const& one, Item const& two) 
{
    return one.type < two.type;
}
```

*type is the string that I am using to sort

How could I change the predicate function to sort the strings alphabetically?

Comment: What is it that does not work at the moment?

Comment: What you're doing should already sort them alphabetically.

Comment: Please show the definition of `Item`. E.g. if `Item::type` is `const char *`, this comparison won't work.

Comment: Also, to be sure to get an answer, the best is to post a minimal working example that reproduces your error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following function will do a case-insensitive compare on two `std::string`s without external libraries (it is C++11 though).

```
bool caseinsensitivecompare(string s1, string s2) {
    locale loc;
    std::transform(s1.begin(),s1.end(),s1.begin(), 
                   [loc](char c){return std::toupper<char>(c,loc);});
    std::transform(s2.begin(),s2.end(),s2.begin(), 
                   [loc](char c){return std::toupper<char>(c,loc);});
    return (s1 < s2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in [Case insensitive string comparison C++ (2012)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9182912/case-insensitive-string-comparison-c), `strcasecmp()` will provide the right answer if comparing `const char *` strings.

If comparing C++ strings, the Boost library has `is_iless()`, for which the header is [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/boost/algorithm/string/compare.hpp), as suggested by [Case insensitive string comparison in C++ (2008)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11635/case-insensitive-string-comparison-in-c).

Comment: yea it was changed from strings to char[16] and sample output is: Ingredient, weapon, armor, weapon... how could i compare the char array then to see which is supposed to be where?

Comment: @AC101 What is it that's unclear to you? Use `strcasecmp()`, just like Simon said (documentation either via google or on linux via `man 3 strcasecmp`).