# How to set the argv[ ] to be case-insensitive in a Win32 Console Application?

Tags: c++, winapi

Solved below.

Original problem:
How can I get comparisons against argv[] to be case-insensitive? Here is a code fragment:

```
if (std::string(argv[2]) == "HKCU") //Si escriben HKCU
{
    cout << "Has escrito HKCU" << endl;
}
else //Si no escriben la clave
{
    cout << "Debes especificar HCKU o HKLM" << endl;
}
```

If I pass the parameter "hkcu" the test does not work, I have to type "HKCU". If I compare for either "HKCU" or "hkcu" in the program either string will work.

**EDIT:** I had to use _stricmp (Using VS2013) this way:

```
if (_stricmp(argv[2], "HKCU") == 0)
```

Comment: Convert the string to be all lowercase...

Comment: Or use the C library function stricompare

Comment: possible duplicate of [Case insensitive string comparison C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9182912/case-insensitive-string-comparison-c)

Comment: @RefugnicEternium: `stricompare` is non-standard.

Comment: **Comparison is case-insensitive while strings can be lower/upper-cased.** So you either use a case-insensitive function to search/compare or you just lower/upper-case the string and use that case in your search string.

Answer (score 3):

If `boost` is an option then you can use `iequals`

```
if (boost::iequals(std::string(argv[2]), "HKCU")) {
  ...
}
```

Another option is to just use `strcasecmp`

```
if (0 == strcasecmp(argv[2], "HKCU")) { 
  ...
}
```

Comment: Why boost for something so simple?

Comment: @JesusRamos no particular reason, i added the `stricmp` solution as well

Comment: `strcasecmp` is more portable than `stricmp`

Comment: @JaredPar it just seems odd (or maybe it's that apparently everyone seems boost is good to solve any problem) that anyone would suggest boost for just a mundane comparison like this?

Comment: Missing a closing paren in the second example.

Comment: @JaredPar thanks a lot but I tried the second one and I still have the same problem. I mean: If I type for example hkcu does not work. Had to type HKCU

Comment: Got it. I had to use _stricmp 'cause the strcmp did not work, and stricmp was deprecated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JesusRamos: You make it sound as if boost is this huge cumbersome tool.  It's not.  It's a tool belt with many many useful tools.  And it's incredibly easy to install on most platforms.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley It's kind of a large tool belt for something as simple as this.

Comment: @JesusRamos: Well, you don't install boost for just this one feature.  But if you have boost, then this feature is available to you, and it deserves a mention.  It's just as good as any of the other options mentioned here(better in my opinion), which are all non-standard.

Answer (score 3):

You need to rethink your question. You don't want the 'string' to be case insensitive, but much rather your comparison to realize, that HKCU is the same as Hkcu or hKcU.

For this end, there's a number of options, one of which is the already mentioned function `stricmp`.
Prototype is:

```
#include <string.h>
int stricmp(const char *string1, const char *string2);
```

Meaning, you'd use it like:

```
if(stricmp(argv[2], "HKCU") == 0) {
}
```

Another option is the `strcasecmp` function which operates similarly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do I have to configure the strcasecmp the same way?

Comment: Got it. I had to use _stricmp 'cause the strcmp did not work, and stricmp was deprecated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Checho If your problem has been solved, please consider accepting the answer that helped you solve it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

argv[] in a C/C++ program is just a string as passed in by the shell. You have to change the comparison in your program to be case-insensitive.