# strcmp returning unexpected results

Tags: c, char, strcmp

I thought strcmp was supposed to return a positive number if the first string was larger than the second string. But this program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char A[] = "A";
    char Aumlaut[] = "Ä";
    printf("%i\n", A[0]);
    printf("%i\n", Aumlaut[0]);
    printf("%i\n", strcmp(A, Aumlaut));
    return 0;
}
```

prints `65`, `-61` and `-1`.

Why? Is there something I'm overlooking?
I thought that maybe the fact that I'm saving as UTF-8 would influence things.. You know because the `Ä` consists of 2 chars there. But saving as an 8-bit encoding and making sure that the strings both have length 1 doesn't help, the end result is the same.
What am I doing wrong?

Using GCC 4.3 under 32 bit Linux here, in case that matters.

Comment: You're using the wrong format specifier. Try `%c` for the correct result.

Comment: @Philip OK, then how would you show that chars are signed in your implementation?

Comment: I wouldn't care. EDIT: as long as I'm on a 2's complement machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `strcmp` and similar comparison functions treat the bytes in the strings as `unsigned char`s, as specified by the standard in section 7.24.4, point 1 (was 7.21.4 in C99)

> The sign of a nonzero value returned by the comparison functions memcmp, strcmp, and strncmp is determined by the sign of the difference between the values of the ﬁrst pair of characters **(both interpreted as unsigned char)** that differ in the objects being compared.

(emphasis mine).

The reason is probably that such an interpretation maintains the ordering between code points in the common encodings, while interpreting them a s signed `char`s doesn't.

Comment: More significantly, if one string has a zero byte in a certain position while another string has something else, the first string should be compare before the second, even if that something else, interpreted as a `char`, would be negative.  One could have a special rule to define the ranking as 0, then -128 to -1, then 1 to 127, but that would be a bit weird.

Answer (score 2):

`strcmp` and the other string functions aren't actually utf aware. On most posix machines, C/C++ `char` is internally utf8, which makes most things "just work" with regards to reading and writing and provide the *option* of a library understanding and manipulating the utf codepoints. But the default `string.h` functions are not culture sensitive and do not know anything about comparing utf strings. You can look at the source code for `strcmp` and see for yourself, it's about as naïve an implementation as possible (which means it's also faster than an internationalization-aware compare function).

I just answered this [in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10444522/c11-case-insensitive-comparison-of-beginning-of-a-string-unicode/10444687#10444687) - you need to use a UTF-aware string library such as IBM's excellent [ICU - International Components for Unicode](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/globalization/icu/).

Comment: I realise that - that's why I said I also tried saving in another charset (Windows-1252 in this case) where `'Ä'` is one char with value -60. But that didn't help, it still prints -1.

Answer (score 1):

Saving as an 8-bit ASCII encoding, `'A' == 65` and `'Ä'` equals whatever -61 is if you consider it to be an `unsigned char`. Anyway, `'Ä'` is strictly positive and greater than 2^7-1, you're just printing it as if it were signed.

If you consider `'Ä'` to be an `unsigned char` (which it is), its value is 195 in your charset. Hence, `strcmp(65, 195)` correctly reports `-1`.

Comment: Are you saying that `strcmp` treats its arguments as _unsigned chars?_ I never read anything about that.

Comment: @MrLister: No. I'm saying that it's implementation-defined whether `char` is really `signed char` or `unsigned char`. In your case, it seems to be `unsigned char`, but you're using `%i` to print its value. Tell `printf()` that you are printing an `unsigned char` instead of a `signed int`.

Comment: @MrLister: That's not true. You tell printf() to consider its argument to be `signed int`, when its argument is indeed an `unsigned char`. Use the correct format specifier, which in this case is `%c`.

Comment: No. This: `printf("%u %u %u\n", (unsigned char)'Ä', (signed char)'Ä', (char)'Ä');` will print 196 for the unsigned char, but 4294967236 for the two others, proving that (char) has the same signage as (signed char).

Comment: This is interesting, since casting the value to equal-sized integer types shouldn't affect the output. Besides, 4294967236 is not representable in 8 bits.

Comment: My guess is that your `strcmp()` implementation is smart enough to perform the comparison using `unsigned char`s.

Comment: That's because it _sign-extends_ the argument when printing as a 32-bit number. (Or for the pedantic, when it pushed an argument onto the stack for a variadic function.)

Comment: If it is smart enough to do unsigned comparison on signed chars, shouldn't that be documented somewhere? I don't like surprises like that.

Comment: True. On the other hand, I don't know of any charset with negative values.

Comment: @MrLister: see http://fossies.org/dox/glibc-2.15/strcmp_8c_source.html (glibc's `strcmp()` implementation). It indeed casts to `unsigned char` before comparison.

Comment: That's beside the point, because it doesn't matter what charset is used. You could write `'\xC4'` and have the same anomalies, on any system.

Comment: ...which is still a miracle to me. `(unsigned char)'Ä'`, `(signed char)'Ä'` and `(char)'Ä'` all have the same bit pattern on a 2's complement machine. When printf() performs sign-extension on all three `%u` arguments, the result should always be the same. Note that printf() doesn't know about the casts... WTF? (:

Comment: I meant my last comment as a reply to "charset with negative values". The fossies page is news to me.

Comment: @Philip Sign-extension only happens for negative values. What happens are the _integer promotions_. When the value of a promoted type can be represented in the target type, the promotion is value-preserving. In Windows-1252, 'Ä' is 196 as an unsigned char, and -60 as a signed char. Both values are representable as `int`, so the call is `printf("%u %u %u\n",196,-60,-60);`. Although strictly, it is undefined behaviour - `%u` requires an `unsigned int` -, you can pretty much rely on the bit-pattern of the `int`s just being interpreted as `unsigned int`s.

Answer (score 1):

strcmp() takes chars as unsigned ASCII values. So, your A-with-double-dots isn't char -61, it's char 195 (or maybe 196, if I've got my math wrong).

Comment: That's what it appears to do, yes. But why?

Comment: @MrLister In an 8-bit encoding like iso-8859-1 or Windows-1252, the code points are numbered 0-255. Treating the contents of the strings as `unsigned char` preserves the ordering of the code points, treating them as signed doesn't. Similarly, with an encoding like utf-8, a higher unicode code-point number yields a lexicographically larger byte sequence when considering the bytes as unsigned, but not when considering them as signed. Probably that's the reason why `strcmp` uses `unsigned char`s.

Comment: @DanielFischer Makes sense. So you mean it's not even implementation dependent? Oh well, I suppose I can live with that, but I'd really have appreciated that if the manual would have said so.

Comment: @MrLister No, it's standard-mandated, see my answer. I agree it would be nice if the man-page said so.

Answer (score 0):

Check the strcmp manpage:

```
The strcmp() function compares the two strings s1 and s2. It returns
an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if s1 is found,
respectively, to be less than, to match, or be greater than s2.
```

Comment: But it doesn't say that -60 is greater than 65. Which is why I asked the question.

Comment: It says -1 becasue the string "A" is less than "Ä". You see the -61 because you print only the first byte of the "Ä" string.

Answer (score -1):

To do string handling correctly in C when the input character set exceeds
UTF8 you should use the standard library's wide-character facilities for
strings and i/o. Your program should be:

```
#include <wchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    wchar_t A[] = L"A";
    wchar_t Aumlaut[] = L"Ä";
    wprintf(L"%i\n", A[0]);
    wprintf(L"%i\n", Aumlaut[0]);
    wprintf(L"%i\n", wcscmp(A, Aumlaut));
    return 0;
}
```

and then it will give the correct results (GCC 4.6.3). You don't need a special library.