# Difference of stricmp and _stricmp in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, case-sensitive, string-comparison, case-insensitive

I may asking a stupid question, but I really can't find an answer with google plus I am still a beginner of using MSVS.

I recently need to use functions to make comparison of two strings. What I don't understand is the difference of stricmp and _stricmp. They both can be used to compare strings and return the same results. I went to check them:

```
char string1[] = "The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox";
char string2[] = "The QUICK brown dog jumps over the lazy fox";

void main( void )
{
   char tmp[20];
   int result;
   /* Case sensitive */
   printf( "Compare strings:\n\t%s\n\t%s\n\n", string1, string2 );
   result = stricmp( string1, string2 );
   if( result > 0 )
      strcpy( tmp, "greater than" );
   else if( result < 0 )
      strcpy( tmp, "less than" );
   else
      strcpy( tmp, "equal to" );
   printf( "\tstricmp:   String 1 is %s string 2\n", tmp );
   /* Case insensitive */
   result = _stricmp( string1, string2 );
   if( result > 0 )
      strcpy( tmp, "greater than" );
   else if( result < 0 )
      strcpy( tmp, "less than" );
   else
      strcpy( tmp, "equal to" );
   printf( "\t_stricmp:  String 1 is %s string 2\n", tmp );
}
```

result shows they are the same:

```
Compare strings:
    The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox
    The QUICK brown dog jumps over the lazy fox

    stricmp:   String 1 is equal to string 2
    _stricmp:  String 1 is equal to string 2
```

I am wondering why...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`stricmp` is a POSIX function, and not a standard C90 function. To avoid name clashes Microsoft deprecated the non-conforming name (`stricmp`) and recommends using `_stricmp` instead. There is no difference in functionality (`stricmp` is merely an alias for `_stricmp`.)

Comment: The leading underscore indicates that it's a vendor specific symbol that shouldn't conflict with any user symbols or future standards.

Comment: Thanks StarPilot. I'll use _stricmp in my project. And other functions works in the same way?

Comment: `stricmp` is **not** a POSIX function, it's a Win32 function. POSIX defines [`strcasecmp`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strcasecmp.html) instead.

Comment: Microsoft states they are POSIX functions in their documentation. For instance, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235365(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @StarPilot Then Microsoft's documentation is wrong. I've searched through POSIX.1-2008 and `stricmp` is not even mentioned in there. As Jonathan Wakely states, POSIX defines `strcasecmp`.

Answer (score 5):

For many library functions, including all the `<string.h>` functions, the underscore prefixed versions are/were Microsoft's idea of something.  I don't recall exactly what.

The non-underscored version is highly portable.  Code which uses `_stricmp()`, `_strcpy()`, etc. must be handled somehow—edit, `#defined`, etc.—if the code will be processed by another compiler.

Comment: However, neither `stricmp` nor `_stricmp` is part of standard C nor C++; technically, `stricmp`  not one of the `<string.h>` functions. But it's a very common extension.

Comment: @PeteBecker:  Yes, though some libraries have `strcmpi()` or `strcasecmp()` instead.

Comment: Thanks your answer wallyk. I think maybe it is very helpful to make the code portable by using 'stricmp' (not `_stricmp`). Since I was looking for the replacement of function `strcasecmp()` and `strncasecmp()`. My understanding so far, is that one can use `(_)stricmp` and `(_)strnicmp` as replacements.