# Case insensitive standard string comparison in C++

Tags: c++, string, substr

```
void
main()
{
    std::string str1 = "abracadabra";
    std::string str2 = "AbRaCaDaBra";

    if (!str1.compare(str2)) {
        cout << "Compares"
    }
}
```

How can I make this work? Bascially make the above case insensitive. Related question
I Googled and here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkcaxw5y.aspx

there is a case insensitive method  String::Compare(str1, str2, Bool). Question is how is that related to the way I am doing.

Comment: Thanks, but there they use boost. My question is is there a way to do the above work without using boost? str1.compare(str2) works and a logical extension to it is to support case insensitive. Is there a simple easy way out?

Comment: David your example appears appealing. I might use it. Thanks

Comment: The link you gave is to a .NET function which is emphatically *not* part of standard C++ and has no relation to it.

Comment: Got it, thanks pardon my ignorance

Comment: I think that the right way of doing this is to define a trait like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11635/case-insensitive-string-comparison-in-c#answer-2886589). That allows you to create a map or a set with case insensitive strings without much work. If you just need to compare two strings in one place, you can always use the `strcasecmp()` function which will also handle the locale properly.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can create a predicate function and use it in `std::equals` to perform the comparison:

```c++
bool icompare_pred(unsigned char a, unsigned char b)
{
    return std::tolower(a) == std::tolower(b);
}

bool icompare(std::string const& a, std::string const& b)
{
    if (a.length()==b.length()) {
        return std::equal(b.begin(), b.end(),
                           a.begin(), icompare_pred);
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now you can simply do:

```c++
if (icompare(str1, str)) {
    std::cout << "Compares" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: This has the advantage that you can set locale and `std::tolower` respects that ; as mentioned elsewhere you're still out of luck if you try to use this on UTF-8

Comment: @0x499602D2: There's a _HUGE_ difference between non-ASCII and non-BMP.  Your code works for ASCII, but not for any codepoints above 127.  BMP doesn't come into this (though it fails for BMP too)

Comment: This isn't a criticism btw, it's not easy to handle UTF-8 properly

Comment: Thanks to all I learnt a lot and finally ended up using this:void
main()
{
    std::string str1 = "abracadabra";
    std::string str2 = "AbRaCaDaBra";

std::transform(str2.begin(), str2.end(), str2.begin(), tolower);
  
 if (!str1.compare(str2)) {
  std::cout << "compares";
 }
}

Comment: I'm not sure this code correctly answers the question. Shouldn't this use `std::equal` instead of `std::lexicographical_compare`? `std::lexicographical_compare` returns `true` if the first argument is __less__ than the second and requires a predicate with the same semantics.

Comment: @Blastfurnace seems to be correct here.  When implemented as-is, you'll get all kinds of fun results.  Like "cow" == "house", or "car" == "cat".

Comment: Trying to compile this in Visual Studio 2015 and getting error:

no instance of function template "std::tolower" matches the argument list
argument types are: (unsigned char)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @ДмитрийКутейко Include `<cctype>`

Answer (score 2):

Covert both to lower case and then compare them.

Converting to lower:

```
for(int i = 0; i < str1.size(); i++)
{
  str[i] = tolower(str[i]);
}
```

Comparing strings:

```
if (str1.compare(str2) == 0) { ... }
```

A zero value indicates that both strings are equal.

**EDIT**

This can be used to avoid for loop: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/transform/

```
std::transform(in.begin(),in.end(),std::back_inserter(out),tolower);
```

Comment: Thanks but I wanted to avoid this and do as we did in stricmp()

Comment: well it is trivial to 'revert' to strcmp, since std::string class supports conversion to C-style string via c_str()

Comment: int.begin()? shouldn't it be in.begin() ?