# error when calling std::equal with a class member function as comparator

Tags: c++

So I was trying to add to a class a function that compares two `std::string`'s disregarding case from here: [Case insensitive standard string comparison in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23943728/case-insensitive-standard-string-comparison-in-c).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class foo {
    public:
        bool icompare_pred(char a, char b) {
             return std::tolower(a) == std::tolower(b);
        }
        bool icompare( string a,  string  b){
            return  equal( a.begin(),  a.end(),  b.begin(),  icompare_pred);
        }
};  

int main() {

}
```

The code doesn't compile, even more: it sends me into the depths of STL with an error

```
[Error] must use '.*' or '->*' to call pointer-to-member function in '__binary_pred (...)', e.g. '(... ->* __binary_pred) (...)'
```

in this part

```
stl_algobase.h
 template<typename _IIter1, typename _IIter2, typename _BinaryPredicate>
inline bool
equal(_IIter1 __first1, _IIter1 __last1,
  _IIter2 __first2, _BinaryPredicate __binary_pred)
{
  // concept requirements
  __glibcxx_function_requires(_InputIteratorConcept<_IIter1>)
  __glibcxx_function_requires(_InputIteratorConcept<_IIter2>)
  __glibcxx_requires_valid_range(__first1, __last1);

  for (; __first1 != __last1; ++__first1, ++__first2)
if (!bool(__binary_pred(*__first1, *__first2)))
  return false;
  return true;
}
```

Well, what do I do? How do I fix this error?

Comment: Make sure to include all the required headers. You're missing `algorithm`, and possibly others.

Comment: This is the basic fact that a member function cannot be used through the same kind of function pointer as a non-member function. (It has its own, but they're distinct and not implicitly convertible, for obvious reasons.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use static function as predicate:

```
static bool icompare_pred(char a, char b) {
^^^^^^
```

or you can use lambda:

```
bool icompare( string a,  string  b){
     return  equal( a.begin(),  a.end(),  b.begin(),  
                      [](char a, char b){return std::tolower(a) == std::tolower(b);});
 }
```

Comment: oh, that was fast! Thank you, detectives, case closed. (in 6 minutes)

Answer (score 2):

Make `icompare_pred()` a static function of `foo`

```
    static bool icompare_pred(char a, char b) {
 // ^^^^^^
         return std::tolower(a) == std::tolower(b);
    }
```

or move the function out of the class `foo` as free function.

Answer (score 1):

You would need your comparator to be `static`

```
static bool icompare_pred(char a, char b) {
    return std::tolower(a) == std::tolower(b);
}
```

Also since `icompare` isn't static, you'd have to call it from a `foo` instance, like so

```
int main()
{
    foo f;
    std::cout << f.icompare("TEST", "test");
}
```

[Live demo](http://cpp.sh/3kint), output

```
1
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple errors in your code, some of which are apparently not caught by your compiler (due to its permissiveness?). For example, `icompare_pred` by itself is not a valid C++ expression. Non-static member function names by themselves do not form valid expressions in C++. You have to either call the function using `()` operator or form a pointer to it using `&` operator and a qualified name. What you are trying to do would be properly expressed as

```
bool icompare( string a,  string  b){
  return  equal( a.begin(),  a.end(),  b.begin(), &foo::icompare_pred);
}
```

Both the `&` operator and the `foo::` prefix are mandatory.

And this is where we run into the second error. A two-parameter non-static member function actually has *three* parameters: the two that you declared explicitly and an implicit `this` parameter. So, in your code you are passing a three-parameter function where a two-parameter one is required. This is one way to "interpret" this error.

In order to make your member function usable as a predicate for `std::equal` you can "bind" the implicit `this` parameter - attach a specific fixed value to it - thus converting a three-parameter function into a two-parameter one. For example

```
bool icompare( string a,  string  b){
  return  equal( a.begin(),  a.end(),  b.begin(),  
    std::bind(&foo::icompare_pred, this, 
      std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));
}
```

This should compile and work as intended.

However, since your comparison predicate does not really need or care about that implicit `this` parameter, a better approach would be to get rid of it entirely: just declare your comparator as `static`, as suggested in other answers. If you do that, the `&foo::icompare_pred` syntax will become unnecessary as well and you'll be able to just use `icompare_pred` in its place as in your original code.

Comment: This is extremely thorough! Thank you!