# Why can I use char but not string with stricmp()?

Tags: c++

This is the code:

```
char s[101], s1[101];
cin >> s >> s1;
cout << stricmp(s, s1);
```

I tried to declare `s` and `s1` as `std::string`, but it didnt work. Can someone explain please why `stricmp()` works with `char[]` but not `std::string`?

Comment: You should probably be a bit more specific when you say "it didn't work." What result are you expecting, and what result are you getting?

Comment: Just because I feel like you don't know about it and it is relevant - do you know what a `char*` is?

Comment: you can declare `s` and `s1` as `std::string`, but instead of calling `stricmp(s, s1);` call it like `stricmp(s.c_str(), s1.c_str());`

Comment: *why is it possible only with chars ? Why cant I input them as strings.* This indicates to me that you don't understand the fundamentals of the language yet. Please learn the fundamentals of the language from [a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: for case insensitive string comparison in C++, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11635/case-insensitive-string-comparison-in-c

Comment: BTW, don't use `cin` with character arrays.  The array lengths are not passed to `cin`, so there is a possibility of buffer overflow.

Answer (score 1):

That is because `stricmp()` doesn' t take `std::string` values as arguments.

Use [`std::basic_string::compare()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare) instead.

```
std::string s ("s");
std::string s1 ("s1");

if (s.compare(s1) != 0) // or just if (s != s1)
  std::cout << s << " is not " << s1 << std::endl;
```

If you need a case-insensitive comparison, you need to make your own function, maybe using `std::tolower()` as in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23943728/case-insensitive-standard-string-comparison-in-c), or just `boost::iequals()` as in [this other example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11635/case-insensitive-string-comparison-in-c).

Comment: `compare` is not a case insensitive compare while `stricmp` is.

Comment: Also, in your example `compare` is not even needed.  You could just write `if (s != s1)`.

Comment: @NathanOliver, thanks for the suggestions, added to the example

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider converting the strings to all upper or all lower case before comparing:

```
std::string s1;
std::string s2;
std::cin >> s1 >> s2;
std::transform(s1.begin(), s1.end(),
               s1.begin(),
               std::tolower);
std::transform(s2.begin(), s2.end(),
               s2.begin(),
               std::tolower);
if (s1 == s2)
{
  std::cout << "s1 and s2 are case insensitive equal.\n";
}
else
{
  std::cout << "s1 and s2 are different.\n";
}
```