# How to find a string in a txt file with case insensitivity and still retain part capitalization? In C++

Tags: c++, string, file, case, capitalization

It would be easy to make everything in the file lowercase and find it, but I want to find the string with the original capitalization so I could put it to a pointer and print it later. For example 
FIND_WORD ransom. 
*File Word found. Line added* 
DISPLAY 
rAnSoM nOtE. yOu HaVe TiLl nOon.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz The question is in the title.

Comment: @NeilKirk Oh. Okay. Then the answer is trivial -- see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Go through the file line by line. For each line, go through the string from beginning to end.

For each starting point in the line, do a case-insensitive compare of the subsequent characters in the string to the characters in the word you're trying to find. If they all match, output that entire line as originally read.

In other words, *don't convert anything to lower case. Instead, do a case-insensitive compare*.

Comment: What does code for a case-insensitive compare look like? if('B'=='b')?

Comment: It can be `if (std::tolower(x) == std::tolower(y))` or look at [these answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11635/case-insensitive-string-comparison-in-c).