# Convert std::string to ci_string

Tags: c++, casting, typedef, case-sensitive, char-traits

I used [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2886589/1015595) to create a case-insensitive typedef for string. Now, I'm trying to convert a `std::string` to `ci_string`. All of the following throw compiler errors:

```
std::string s {"a"};
ci_string cis {s};
ci_string cis (s);
ci_string cis {(ci_string)s};
ci_string cis ((ci_string)s);
ci_string cis = s;
```

I spent some time trying to figure out how to overload the `=` operator, and I attempted to use `static_cast` and `dynamic_cast` without success. How can I do this?

Comment: Just read the comments below the answer you linked to - those two string types are not compatible. That's why none of your versions work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two types are different, so you cannot use the constructor with a regular `std::string`. But your string is still able to copy a C string, so this should work:

```
std::string s{"a"};
ci_string cis{ s.data() }; // or s.c_str(), they are the same
```

Answer (score 1):

`std::string` and `ci_string` are **unrelated types**. Why would `static_cast` or `dynamic_cast` be able to convert them? Remember: Two different instantiations of the same template are unrelated types and are potentially completely incompatible.

Give up on the idea of overloading `operator=` or on some magic that performs the conversion automatically. You have two unrelated types. But they both offer member functions that can you can successfully use to copy the `char` elements from one to the other.

Just write a simple conversion function that takes advantage of the fact that both `std::string` and `ci_string` have their `value_type` defined as `char`, and appropriately use one of [`std::basic_string`'s constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string), either one which takes a pointer to raw data or one which takes two iterators which form a range.

Here is a complete example:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct ci_char_traits : public std::char_traits<char> {
    static bool eq(char c1, char c2) { return toupper(c1) == toupper(c2); }
    static bool ne(char c1, char c2) { return toupper(c1) != toupper(c2); }
    static bool lt(char c1, char c2) { return toupper(c1) <  toupper(c2); }
    static int compare(const char* s1, const char* s2, size_t n) {
        while( n-- != 0 ) {
            if( toupper(*s1) < toupper(*s2) ) return -1;
            if( toupper(*s1) > toupper(*s2) ) return 1;
            ++s1; ++s2;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    static const char* find(const char* s, int n, char a) {
        while( n-- > 0 && toupper(*s) != toupper(a) ) {
            ++s;
        }
        return s;
    }
};

typedef std::basic_string<char, ci_char_traits> ci_string;

ci_string to_ci_string(std::string const& src)
{
    return ci_string(src.begin(), src.end());
    // or:
    // return ci_string(src.c_str());
}

int main()
{
    std::string s {"a"};
    auto cis = to_ci_string(s);

    std::cout << cis.c_str() << "\n";
}
```