# Case insensitive c++ sort that accepts all datatypes?

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, normalization

I am still relatively new to programming and I've done a lot of research on how to implement this, but I cannot figure it out.

I've been using this case insensitive sort:

```
    for (size_t i = 0; i < copy.size() - 1; i++) //use copy vector to organize in ascending order
    {
        int smallest = i;
        for (size_t j = i + 1; j < copy.size(); j++)
        {
            if (tolower(copy[j]) < tolower(copy[smallest])) //normalizes capitals and lowercases
                smallest = j;
        }
        int temp = copy[smallest];
        copy[smallest] = copy[i];
        copy[i] = temp;
    }
```

Which works fine until I pass a vector of type string in. How can I make this sort universal for all datatypes while still making it case insensitive?

Comment: *"universal for all datatypes while still making it case insensitive"*. Case insensitivity has only sense for characters or strings, not all datatypes.

Comment: related/dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11635/case-insensitive-string-comparison-in-c

Comment: I realize cast insensitivity applies to chars and strings, but my vector may be initialized to ints and I wanted it to still work in which ever case.

Comment: But how do you sort ints case insensitively?

Comment: So I need to recognize that my vector is of ints and sort it with a different sort algorithm. And then if it is char or string then I need to sort it with one that ignore case insensitivity. There is no way I can call one sort function?

Comment: Alright, that's possible, with some templates and specialization.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `std::sort()` with your own comparison function.

Bye the way, I think you do not need Case insensitive for all datatypes.

For your comment in question: you can always ignore the 3rd parameter if you want default comparison.

Example:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cctype>  //toupper
using namespace std;

bool CompareStringCaseInsensitive(const string& lhs,const string& rhs){

   string::size_type common_length = std::min(lhs.length(),rhs.length());

   for(string::size_type i=0;i<common_length;++i){
      if(toupper(lhs[i]) < toupper(rhs[i]))return true;
      if(toupper(lhs[i]) > toupper(rhs[i]))return false;
   }

   if(lhs.length()<rhs.length())return true;
   if(lhs.length()>rhs.length())return false;//can ignore

   return false;//equal should return false
}

int main(){
   vector<string> testdata{"a","B","c","D"};

   cout << "Sort By Default :" << '\n';
   sort(testdata.begin(),testdata.end());
   for(const auto& s : testdata){cout << s << ' ';}
   cout << '\n';

   cout << "Sort CaseInsensitive :" << '\n';
   sort(testdata.begin(),testdata.end(),CompareStringCaseInsensitive);
   for(const auto& s : testdata){cout << s << ' ';}
}
```

Comment: So in the third parameter of sort, should I call a function like the one used here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11635/case-insensitive-string-comparison-in-c

Comment: Yes you can, if you don't want to use boost, you can implement your own.