# strcasecmp. unsolvable error message

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <strings.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s = "test";
    if(strcasecmp(s, "TEST"))
        cout << "equals"<< endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Help needed on how to use strcasecmp, when i tried to compile, the compiler keep shows an error message

> error: cannot convert ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string}’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int strcasecmp(const char*, const char*)

Comment: try with `strcasecmp(s.c_str(), "TEST")`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11635/case-insensitive-string-comparison-in-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `strcasecmp()` function expects a pointer to a null-terminated `char` string, you cannot pass a `std::string` directly to it.

The correct way to use this should be:

```
strcasecmp(s.c_str(), "TEST")
```

Moreover, the code looks incorrect in your program, because `strcasecmp()` returns a ZERO in case the strings are equal. So, you should be using the following:

```
if(strcasecmp(s, "TEST") == 0)
    cout << "equals"<< endl;
```

Answer (score 4):

`strcasecmp` takes a `const char*`, not a `std::string` as argument. Use `strcasecmp(s.c_str(), "TEST")` instead, or have a `s` be a C-style string in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

It means `strcasecmp` expect a C style string (`0` terminated `char[]`) not a C++ `string`. You can get one with `s.c_str()`.

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```
strcasecmp(s.c_str(), "TEST")
```

Comment: you cannot cast a string into char*

Answer (score 0):

The `strcasecmp()` function is [not specified](https://c-for-dummies.com/blog/?p=3863) in the C International standard. However, `strcasecmp()` is part of the *POSIX.1-2001* and *4.4BSD* [specifications](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcasecmp).

Under Cygwin you even need the additional line

```cpp
#include <strings.h>
```

to make this function available in your own code.

To keep your code portable, I would forgo this function and rebuild its functionality myself:

```cpp
int StringCaseCompare (const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2)
{
  if ( &s1 == &s2 )
    return 0;

  auto iter1 = s1.cbegin();
  auto iter2 = s2.cbegin();
  
  while ( iter1 != s1.cend() )
  {
    if ( iter2 != s2.cend() )
    {
      int cmp = int(std::tolower(*iter1)) - int(std::tolower(*iter2));

      if ( cmp != 0 )
        return cmp;

      ++iter2;
    }
    else
      return int(std::tolower(*iter1));

    ++iter1;
  }

  return -int(std::tolower(*iter2));
}
```