# C++ How to ignore the difference between upper and lower when checking Anagram?

Tags: c++, for-loop, anagram

```
bool isAnagram(string s1, string s2){
   if(s1.length() != s2.length())
      return false;

  for(int i =0; i <s1.length();i++){
      int pos = (s2.find(s1[i]);
                 if(pos<0)
                 return false;
                 s2.erase(pos,1);

               }
                 return true;

                 return false;

               }
```

I write the code about checking Anagram but ignore the requirement of ignoring difference between upper and lower. I have no idea about that. Can you help me? Thanks!

Comment: Initially I was going to mark this as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11635/case-insensitive-string-comparison-in-c but those answers are so old it's not funny. Regardless, I downvoted because this is so simple to look up you'd have literally spent less time googling "c++ ignore case"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert both to lowercase before comparing

```
std::transform(s1.begin(), s1.end(), s1.begin(), ::tolower);
std::transform(s2.begin(), s2.end(), s2.begin(), ::tolower);
```

Comment: Do I need to write a new function?

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is set both string to lower case(or upper case), and then sort both of them. If `s1` and `s2` is anagram to each other, then the result should be same.

Answer (score 0):

you can use algorithm library to convert uppercase to lowercase.
before looping add below line to convert it to lower case.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
std::transform(s1.begin(), s1.end(), s1.begin(), ::tolower);
std::transform(s2.begin(), s2.end(), s2.begin(), ::tolower);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the power of the STL `algorithm`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

bool isSameChar(int a, int b)
{
    return tolower(a) == tolower(b);
}

bool isAnagram(const string& a, const string& b)
{
    return a.size() == b.size()
        && is_permutation(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), isSameChar);
}

int main()
{
    cout << isAnagram("AbcDE", "ebCda") << endl; // true
    cout << isAnagram("AbcDE", "ebCdaa") << endl; // false
    cout << isAnagram("AbcDE", "ebCde") << endl; // false

    return 0;
}
```