# How do i make 2 inputs case insensitive in c++?

Tags: c++

```
cout << "Please enter colors for the two cuboids: " ;
cin >> color1 >> color2;


if ( color1 == color2)
    cout << "Color names cannot be the same, good bye..." << endl;
```

Like here I need to check if color 1 is equal to color2 for example rEd and RED should be considered the same but I should not use for loops to solve this is there any other way?

Comment: You can use `while` loop instead of `for` loops. `for(A; B; D) C` is almost equivalent to `A; while(B) { C D; }`

Comment: Should not use for loops? What's the reason for this? Are you doing some kind of quiz?

Comment: @MikeCAT It's highly unlikely that will be accepted by whoever set the assignment. The spirit of the task is clearly to avoid loops altogether.

Comment: You could use `std::transform` to convert your strings to lower case. But `std::transform` uses a for loop internally. Does that count?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings It may be accepted if the task is for leaning `while` loop.

Comment: I guess you are supposed to use recursion. But rather than second guess, why not ask the person who set this problem what the intention is.

Comment: Then that would be the wording of the task @Mike

Comment: You could use [boost::iequals](https://stackoverflow.com/a/315463/4641116).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution with no loops. It converts each character in the string to lower case before comparing them, and uses *tail recursion* to iterate over the string. I'm guessing this is the intention of the problem you've been set, though some would say that tail recursion is a loop as well.

```
#include <cctype>
#include <string>

bool string_eq_ci(const std::string& x, const std::string& y);
bool string_loop(const std::string& x, const std::string& y, size_t i);

    ...
    if (string_eq_ci(color1, color2)))
        cout << "Color names cannot be the same, good bye..." << endl;
    ...

bool string_eq_ci(const std::string& x, const std::string& y)
{
    return x.size() == y.size() && string_loop(x, y, 0);
}

bool string_loop(const std::string& x, const std::string& y, size_t i)
{
    return i == x.size() || (
            tolower(static_cast<unsigned char>(x[i])) == 
            tolower(static_cast<unsigned char>(y[i])) && 
        string_loop(x, y, i + 1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either of:

1. Use [strcasecmp](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcasecmp)(), for example:

   if(strcasecmp(color1.c_str(), color2.c_str()) == 0) { .. equal colors.. }
2. Convert both colors to lowercase (or uppercase), and compare strings, as you wrote in your question.You can do it with [std::toupper](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper).

Comment: Can you write me the code for second one?  Every time i try it it says no suitable conversion from std::string to int although color is not an int.

Comment: Click link over the "std::toupper".

Answer (score 0):

For English colors without any iteration (loops, recursion, etc.) (beside those of IO operations):

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string color1;
    std::string color2;

    std::cout << "Please enter colors for the two cuboids: " ;
    std::cin >> color1 >> color2;
    
    if ( (color1.size() == color2.size()) 
        && ( (color1.front() | 0x20) == (color2.front() | 0x20) )
        && ( (color1.back() | 0x20) == (color2.back() | 0x20) )
       )
        std::cout << "Color names cannot be the same, good bye..." << std::endl;
}
```

[wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/yWi9qwfTpB1lXD69)

Exclaimer:

This is a little bit of a joke.
I did not check if this code works ok for all colors and it may be wrong. But even so there may be a way to write code without any iterations.

Answer (score 0):

Since your assignment requires you not to write loops, my guess is that you are expected to use algorithms instead. This is a good thing, since algorithms often convey the intent of the code better than loops can.

Here's a function copied directly from [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower) that converts all the characters of a string to lowercase:

```
std::string str_tolower(std::string s) {
    std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), 
                   [](unsigned char c){ return std::tolower(c); } 
                  );
    return s;
}
```

Now you can use this function in the comparison of the strings like this:

```
if (str_tolower(color1) == str_tolower(color2))
  // ...
```