# How to compare two strings which can have null character \0 in between in C++?

Tags: c++, strcmp

I want to compare two strings s1 and s2 and both strings can have null characters in between.
I want both case sensitive and insensitive compare like strcmp and strcasecmp.
Suppose my strings are:

```
std::string s1="Abcd\0abcd"
std::string s2="Abcd\0cccc"
```

Currently, I'm doing `strcmp(s1.c_str(), s2.c_str())` and `strcasecmp(s1.c_str(), s2.c_str())` but `strcasecmp` and `strcmp` end up giving equal in this case and skip the comparison after `\0`.
Any libraries I can use to compare these strings.

Comment: Well, SOMEONE has to tell it the actual length.  There's no way to tell that.  `memcmp` can compare two arbitrary memory buffers.

Comment: @TimRoberts I can pass the length, memcmp works well for case sensitive comparison, anything for case insensitive as well?

Comment: Why do you need this? What is your use case?

Comment: Where are these "strings" coming from? Why do you need to compare them?

Comment: Just convert [to lowercase](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower) if you want case-insensitive compare

Comment: And std::string constructed using literals [already does the job](https://godbolt.org/z/jWq8f6Pcq)

Comment: That is four strings, two without a symbol to directly reference them.  Looks like an X-Y problem.  Whatever you are trying to do, ask about that, because there is likely a better solution.  Moreover, given this is C++ "string" is ambiguous.  Are s1, s2 `const char*`, `char[]` or `std::string`?

Comment: You probably want `"Abcd\0abcd"s`, actually, your `std::string` doesn't have `\0` in the middle.

Answer (score 11):

#### Case-sensitive comparison

Case-sensitive comparison is simple.
However, we need to use the [`sv` literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/operator%22%22sv) to make a [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) that can contain null characters. Some of its constructors could also handle it, but no solution is as concise as  `sv` literals (or `s` for `std::string`).

```cpp
using namespace std::string_view_literals;

// prior to C++17, you can use std::string and "..."s
std::string_view s1 = "Abcd\0abcd"sv;
std::string_view s2 = "Abcd\0cccc"sv;

bool eq = s1 == s2; // false
```

[`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) already doesn't care about null characters in the string, so you can use the overloaded `==` operator.

In general, you should avoid C functions like `strcmp`; there are much better alternatives in C++ that don't require null-terminated strings.

#### Case-insensitive comparison

Case-insensitive comparison is slightly more difficult, but can be easily done with [`std::ranges::equal`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/equal) or [`std::equal`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal).

```cpp
#include <cctype>    // std::tolower
#include <algorithm> // std::ranges::equal or std::equal

// C++20
bool eq = std::ranges::equal(s1, s2, [](unsigned char a, unsigned char b) {
    return std::tolower(a) == std::tolower(b);
});
```

```cpp
// legacy
bool eq = std::equal(std::begin(s1), std::end(s1), std::begin(s2), std::end(s2),
    [](unsigned char a, unsigned char b) {
        return std::tolower(a) == std::tolower(b);
    });
```

*Note: it's important that the lambda accepts `unsigned char`, not `char`; [`std::tolower`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower) doesn't work properly if we input negative values, and `char` may be negative.*

*Note: `std::tolower` doesn't handle unicode strings. See also [Case-insensitive string comparison in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11635/5740428) for more robust solutions.*

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
std::string s1="Abcd\0abcd"
```

Will result in std::string getting assigned `"Abcd"` since the assignment will stop at the first null char in the string literal.

This will include the full binary string with the null chars that appear in the middle.

```
std::string s1("Abcd\0abcd", 9);
std::string s2=("Abcd\0cccc", 9);
```

Then you can do:

```
if (s1 < s2) {
}
```

Or case insensitive:

```
auto s1lower = s1;
std::transform(s1lower.begin(), s1lower.end(), s1lower.begin(),
[](char c){ return std::tolower(c); });

auto s2lower = s2;
std::transform(s2lower.begin(), s2lower.end(), s2lower.begin(),
[](char c){ return std::tolower(c); });

if (s1lower < s2lower) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: `s/char/unsigned char/` to avoid possible UB :-(