# Convert a unicode String In C++ To Upper Case

Tags: c++, string, unicode

How we can convert a multi language string or unicode string to upper/lower case in C or C++.

Comment: Check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614595/converting-wide-char-string-to-lowercase-in-c. It might help you.

Comment: What do you mean by "Unicode"? There are lots of different encodings defined by the Unicode standard—which one are you using? UTF-8? UTF-16? UTF-32?

Comment: google it before risa a question here

Comment: With unicode, be very wary if using an all-uppercase comparison, since many implementations don't properly check which characters are uppercase or lowercase.

Comment: http://site.icu-project.org/

Answer (score 13):

If your system is already in UTF-8, by using [`std::use_facet`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/use_facet), you can write:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale.h>

int main() {
    std::locale::global(std::locale(""));  // (*)
    std::wcout.imbue(std::locale());
    auto& f = std::use_facet<std::ctype<wchar_t>>(std::locale());

    std::wstring str = L"Zoë Saldaña played in La maldición del padre Cardona.";

    f.toupper(&str[0], &str[0] + str.size());
    std::wcout << str << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And you get (http://ideone.com/AFHoHC):

> ZOË SALDAÑA PLAYED IN LA MALDICIÓN DEL PADRE CARDONA.

If it don't work you will have to change **(*)** into `std::locale::global(std::locale("en_US.UTF8"));` or an UTF-8 locale you actually have on the plateform.

Comment: This is if your stdlib has locale support, and your UTF-8 locale is named "en_US.UTF8". It's a good C++ solution, but that C++ solution is in itself quite unportable.

Comment: @rubenvb: Yes, of course you have to check if the UTF-8 locale exist. Actually wouldn't `std::locale::global(std::locale(""))` do the job?

Comment: @Kyle_the_hacker This code is works if I set std::locale::global(std::locale("en_US.UTF-8"));
on Apple LLVM 4.2 Compiler but not on LLVM GCC 4.2 compiler.
I think 'auto' is not supported in LLVM GCC.

Comment: @Pankaj: Wow, that's an old compiler! Try to replace `auto&` with `const std::ctype<wchar_t>&`.

Answer (score 5):

If you want a sane and mature solution, look at [IBM's ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/). Here's an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unicode/unistr.h>
#include <string>

int main(){
    icu::UnicodeString us("óóßChloë");
    us.toUpper(); //convert to uppercase in-place
    std::string s;
    us.toUTF8String(s);
    std::cout<<"Upper: "<<s<<"\n";

    us.toLower(); //convert to lowercase in-place
    s.clear();
    us.toUTF8String(s);
    std::cout<<"Lower: "<<s<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Upper: ÓÓSSCHLOË
Lower: óósschloë
```

**Note:** In the later step `SS` isn't being treated as capital of German `ß`

Comment: That does look like a nice library. However, it clocks in at almost 30MB. My entire app is 21MB.

Answer (score 4):

I found 2 solution of that problem_

1.
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "en_US.UTF-8"); // the locale will be the UTF-8 enabled English

```
std::wstring str = L"Zoë Saldaña played in La maldición del padre Cardona.ëèñ";

std::wcout << str << std::endl;

for (wstring::iterator it = str.begin(); it != str.end(); ++it)
    *it = towupper(*it);

std::wcout << "toUpper_onGCC_LLVM_1 :: "<< str << std::endl;
```

this is working on LLVM GCC 4.2 Compiler.

2.
std::locale::global(std::locale("en_US.UTF-8"));  // the locale will be the UTF-8 enabled English

```
std::wcout.imbue(std::locale());
const std::ctype<wchar_t>& f = std::use_facet< std::ctype<wchar_t> >(std::locale());

std::wstring str = L"Chloëè";//"Zoë Saldaña played in La maldición del padre Cardona.";

f.toupper(&str[0], &str[0] + str.size());   

std::wcout << str << std::endl;
```

This is working in Apple LLVM 4.2.

Both case i ran on Xocde.
But I am finding a way to run this code in Eclipse with g++ Compiler.

Comment: Did you read the other answers? You basically copy/pasted @mewa's and my answer...

Answer (score 3):

With quite a lot of difficulty if you're going to do it right.

The usual use-case for this is for comparison purposes, but the problem is more general than that.

There is a fairly detailed paper from C++ Report circa 2000 from Matt Austern [here](http://lafstern.org/matt/col2_new.pdf) (PDF)

Comment: Uppercasing for case-insensitive comparison is just the wrong approach. The right approach is to get rid *only* of the case differences (there's an operation known as "casefolding" that can be used for this) and then compare. Uppercasing does not get rid of *only* the case differences.

Comment: I'd even disagree with that statement. You want to get rid of all differences that are irrelevant to the comparison. Sure, `Æ = æ`, but that probably is equal to AE, ae and AE as well.

Comment: This is not an answer

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate through a `wstring` and use [towupper](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwctype/towupper/) / [towlower](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwctype/towlower/?kw=towlower)

```
for (wstring::iterator it = a.begin(); it != a.end(); ++it)
        *it = towupper(*it);
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the [locale first](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x99tb11d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), example :

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "German")); /*This won't work as per comments below */

setlocale(LC_ALL, "English"));

setlocale( LC_MONETARY, "French" );

setlocale( LC_ALL, "" ); //default locale
```

Then use

[std::use_facet](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/locale/use_facet/)  [std::locale](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/locale/locale/)  as follows:-

```
typedef std::string::value_type char_t;
char_t upcase( char_t ch )
{
 return std::use_facet< std::ctype< char_t > >( std::locale() ).toupper( ch );
}

std::string toupper( const std::string &src )
{
 std::string result;
 std::transform( src.begin(), src.end(), std::back_inserter( result ), upcase );
 return result;
}

const std::string src  = "Hello World!";
std::cout << toupper( src );
```

Comment: Funny that you mention the German locale, and then proceed to use a method that won't work for proper German uppercasing, because it uses a 1-to-1 map (`transform`), but uppercasing ß results in two characters.

Comment: Actually I want to convert french text so I am using 
setlocale( LC_MONETARY, "French" );
But getting CHLOë as output when I converting chloë to upper case.

Comment: @Pankaj please, please, please, stop programming by accident. What do you think `setlocale(LC_MONETARY, "French")` does? Do you think uppercasing "Chloë" has any monetary concerns in it? If your problem is finding the documentation, it's here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/setlocale and here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/LC_categories

Comment: @Pankaj what you exactly want from "Chloë ? please leave her alone ;)

Comment: @P0W Cholë should be come like CHOLË after changing to uppercase.

Answer (score 2):

In Windows, consider `CharUpperBuffW` and `CharLowerBuffW` for mixed-language applications where locale is unknown. These functions handle diacritics where `toupper()` does not.

Comment: There are only downsides to using platform specific functions to manipulate text -- it binds your code to that platform and doesn't do you any good. Considering that there are many good text manipulation libraries that are not platform specific, you're just hurting yourself by doing this.

Comment: It is naïve to assume that it is beneficial or profitable to run all applications on all platforms.

Comment: It's naive to assume that your program will never run on any other platform than the one you're developing on right now. It's downright stupid to tie yourself to a platform by using an inferior API, when a superior non-platform specific API exists.

Answer (score 0):

For C I would use `toupper` after adjusting the C locale in the current thread.

```
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "en_US.UTF8");
```

For C++ I would use the `toupper` method of `std::ctype<char>`:

```
std::locale loc;

auto& f = std::use_facet<std::ctype<char>>(loc);

char str[80] = "Hello World";

f.toupper(str, str+strlen(str));
```

Comment: my code is:-

setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "en_US.UTF8");
    
    std::locale loc;
    
    auto& f = std::use_facet<std::ctype<char>>(loc);
    
    char str[80] = "pièces";
    
    f.toupper(str, str+strlen(str));
    
    cout<<str;


but I am getting output as - PIèCES

Comment: @Pankaj that's because the en_US locale doesn't have uppercase forms for anything that isn't in a-z.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes So what i have to do for that,actually I am very new to CPP and I even dont know hello world programme properly in CPP.
some how I managing that..

Comment: @Pankaj: Use the appropriate locale. For instance, in Turkish the uppercase of i is İ (keeping the dot above). The Turkish locale knows this, the US knows that uppercase i is I without a dot. Both are right, of course.

Comment: @Kyle_the_hacker oh, I missed how Pankaj was using cout to print stuff. Good point.

Comment: @MSalters so what is  setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "en_US.UTF8"); locale of Turkish then please?

Comment: @gokturk: Probably `"tr_TR.UTF8"`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Kyle_the_hacker's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1689664/kyle-the-hacker) -----> [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17993266/3158594) with my extras.

## Ubuntu

In terminal
List all locales
`locale -a`

Install all locales
`sudo apt-get install -y locales locales-all`

Compile main.cpp
`$ g++ main.cpp`

Run compiled program
`$ ./a.out`

**Results**

```
Zoë Saldaña played in La maldición del padre Cardona. ëèñ αω óóChloë
Zoë Saldaña played in La maldición del padre Cardona. ëèñ αω óóChloë
ZOË SALDAÑA PLAYED IN LA MALDICIÓN DEL PADRE CARDONA. ËÈÑ ΑΩ ÓÓCHLOË
ZOË SALDAÑA PLAYED IN LA MALDICIÓN DEL PADRE CARDONA. ËÈÑ ΑΩ ÓÓCHLOË
zoë saldaña played in la maldición del padre cardona. ëèñ αω óóchloë
zoë saldaña played in la maldición del padre cardona. ëèñ αω óóchloë
```

[image: Ubuntu Linux - WSL from VSCODE]

[image: Ubuntu Linux - WSL]

## Windows

In cmd run VCVARS developer tools
`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat"`

Compile main.cpp
`> cl /EHa main.cpp  /D "_DEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /std:c++17  /DYNAMICBASE "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib"  /MTd`

```
Compilador de optimización de C/C++ de Microsoft (R) versión 19.27.29111 para x64
(C) Microsoft Corporation. Todos los derechos reservados.

main.cpp
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.27.29111.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:main.exe
main.obj
kernel32.lib
user32.lib
gdi32.lib
winspool.lib
comdlg32.lib
advapi32.lib
shell32.lib
ole32.lib
oleaut32.lib
uuid.lib
odbc32.lib
odbccp32.lib
```

Run main.exe
`>main.exe`

**Results**

```
Zoë Saldaña played in La maldición del padre Cardona. ëèñ αω óóChloë
Zoë Saldaña played in La maldición del padre Cardona. ëèñ αω óóChloë
ZOË SALDAÑA PLAYED IN LA MALDICIÓN DEL PADRE CARDONA. ËÈÑ ΑΩ ÓÓCHLOË
ZOË SALDAÑA PLAYED IN LA MALDICIÓN DEL PADRE CARDONA. ËÈÑ ΑΩ ÓÓCHLOË
zoë saldaña played in la maldición del padre cardona. ëèñ αω óóchloë
zoë saldaña played in la maldición del padre cardona. ëèñ αω óóchloë
```

[image: Windows]

### The code - main.cpp

> **This code was only tested on Windows x64 and Ubuntu Linux x64.**

```cpp
/*
 * Filename: c:\Users\x\Cpp\main.cpp
 * Path: c:\Users\x\Cpp
 * Filename: /home/x/Cpp/main.cpp
 * Path: /home/x/Cpp
 * Created Date: Saturday, October 17th 2020, 10:43:31 pm
 * Author: Joma
 *
 * No Copyright 2020
 */


#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <locale>

// WINDOWS
#if (_WIN32)
#include <Windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define WINDOWS_PLATFORM 1
#define DLLCALL STDCALL
#define DLLIMPORT _declspec(dllimport)
#define DLLEXPORT _declspec(dllexport)
#define DLLPRIVATE
#define NOMINMAX

//EMSCRIPTEN
#elif defined(__EMSCRIPTEN__)
#include <emscripten/emscripten.h>
#include <emscripten/bind.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>
#define EMSCRIPTEN_PLATFORM 1
#define DLLCALL
#define DLLIMPORT
#define DLLEXPORT __attribute__((visibility("default")))
#define DLLPRIVATE __attribute__((visibility("hidden")))

// LINUX - Ubuntu, Fedora, , Centos, Debian, RedHat
#elif (__LINUX__ || __gnu_linux__ || __linux__ || __linux || linux)
#define LINUX_PLATFORM 1
#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>
#define DLLCALL CDECL
#define DLLIMPORT
#define DLLEXPORT __attribute__((visibility("default")))
#define DLLPRIVATE __attribute__((visibility("hidden")))
#define CoTaskMemAlloc(p) malloc(p)
#define CoTaskMemFree(p) free(p)

//ANDROID
#elif (__ANDROID__ || ANDROID)
#define ANDROID_PLATFORM 1
#define DLLCALL
#define DLLIMPORT
#define DLLEXPORT __attribute__((visibility("default")))
#define DLLPRIVATE __attribute__((visibility("hidden")))

//MACOS
#elif defined(__APPLE__)
#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>
#define DLLCALL
#define DLLIMPORT
#define DLLEXPORT __attribute__((visibility("default")))
#define DLLPRIVATE __attribute__((visibility("hidden")))
#include "TargetConditionals.h"
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE && TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
#define IOS_SIMULATOR_PLATFORM 1
#elif TARGET_OS_IPHONE
#define IOS_PLATFORM 1
#elif TARGET_OS_MAC
#define MACOS_PLATFORM 1
#else

#endif

#endif



typedef std::string String;
typedef std::wstring WString;

#define EMPTY_STRING u8""s
#define EMPTY_WSTRING L""s

using namespace std::literals::string_literals;

class Strings
{
public:
    static String WideStringToString(const WString& wstr)
    {
        if (wstr.empty())
        {
            return String();
        }
        size_t pos;
        size_t begin = 0;
        String ret;

#if WINDOWS_PLATFORM
        int size;
        pos = wstr.find(static_cast<wchar_t>(0), begin);
        while (pos != WString::npos && begin < wstr.length())
        {
            WString segment = WString(&wstr[begin], pos - begin);
            size = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, WC_ERR_INVALID_CHARS, &segment[0], segment.size(), NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
            String converted = String(size, 0);
            WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, WC_ERR_INVALID_CHARS, &segment[0], segment.size(), &converted[0], converted.size(), NULL, NULL);
            ret.append(converted);
            ret.append({ 0 });
            begin = pos + 1;
            pos = wstr.find(static_cast<wchar_t>(0), begin);
        }
        if (begin <= wstr.length())
        {
            WString segment = WString(&wstr[begin], wstr.length() - begin);
            size = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, WC_ERR_INVALID_CHARS, &segment[0], segment.size(), NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
            String converted = String(size, 0);
            WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, WC_ERR_INVALID_CHARS, &segment[0], segment.size(), &converted[0], converted.size(), NULL, NULL);
            ret.append(converted);
        }
#elif LINUX_PLATFORM || MACOS_PLATFORM || EMSCRIPTEN_PLATFORM
        size_t size;
        pos = wstr.find(static_cast<wchar_t>(0), begin);
        while (pos != WString::npos && begin < wstr.length())
        {
            WString segment = WString(&wstr[begin], pos - begin);
            size = wcstombs(nullptr, segment.c_str(), 0);
            String converted = String(size, 0);
            wcstombs(&converted[0], segment.c_str(), converted.size());
            ret.append(converted);
            ret.append({ 0 });
            begin = pos + 1;
            pos = wstr.find(static_cast<wchar_t>(0), begin);
        }
        if (begin <= wstr.length())
        {
            WString segment = WString(&wstr[begin], wstr.length() - begin);
            size = wcstombs(nullptr, segment.c_str(), 0);
            String converted = String(size, 0);
            wcstombs(&converted[0], segment.c_str(), converted.size());
            ret.append(converted);
        }
#else
        static_assert(false, "Unknown Platform");
#endif
        return ret;
    }

    static WString StringToWideString(const String& str)
    {
        if (str.empty())
        {
            return WString();
        }

        size_t pos;
        size_t begin = 0;
        WString ret;
#ifdef WINDOWS_PLATFORM
        int size = 0;
        pos = str.find(static_cast<char>(0), begin);
        while (pos != std::string::npos) {
            std::string segment = std::string(&str[begin], pos - begin);
            std::wstring converted = std::wstring(segment.size() + 1, 0);
            size = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, MB_ERR_INVALID_CHARS, &segment[0], segment.size(), &converted[0], converted.length());
            converted.resize(size);
            ret.append(converted);
            ret.append({ 0 });
            begin = pos + 1;
            pos = str.find(static_cast<char>(0), begin);
        }
        if (begin < str.length()) {
            std::string segment = std::string(&str[begin], str.length() - begin);
            std::wstring converted = std::wstring(segment.size() + 1, 0);
            size = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, MB_ERR_INVALID_CHARS, segment.c_str(), segment.size(), &converted[0], converted.length());
            converted.resize(size);
            ret.append(converted);
        }

#elif LINUX_PLATFORM || MACOS_PLATFORM || EMSCRIPTEN_PLATFORM
        size_t size;
        pos = str.find(static_cast<char>(0), begin);
        while (pos != String::npos)
        {
            String segment = String(&str[begin], pos - begin);
            WString converted = WString(segment.size(), 0);
            size = mbstowcs(&converted[0], &segment[0], converted.size());
            converted.resize(size);
            ret.append(converted);
            ret.append({ 0 });
            begin = pos + 1;
            pos = str.find(static_cast<char>(0), begin);
        }
        if (begin < str.length())
        {
            String segment = String(&str[begin], str.length() - begin);
            WString converted = WString(segment.size(), 0);
            size = mbstowcs(&converted[0], &segment[0], converted.size());
            converted.resize(size);
            ret.append(converted);
        }
#else
        static_assert(false, "Unknown Platform");
#endif
        return ret;
    }


    static WString ToUpper(const WString& data)
    {
        WString result = data;
        auto& f = std::use_facet<std::ctype<wchar_t>>(std::locale());

        f.toupper(&result[0], &result[0] + result.size());
        return result;
    }

    static String  ToUpper(const String& data)
    {
        return WideStringToString(ToUpper(StringToWideString(data)));
    }

    static WString ToLower(const WString& data)
    {
        WString result = data;
        auto& f = std::use_facet<std::ctype<wchar_t>>(std::locale());
        f.tolower(&result[0], &result[0] + result.size());
        return result;
    }

    static String ToLower(const String& data)
    {
        return WideStringToString(ToLower(StringToWideString(data)));
    }

};

enum class ConsoleTextStyle
{
    DEFAULT = 0,
    BOLD = 1,
    FAINT = 2,
    ITALIC = 3,
    UNDERLINE = 4,
    SLOW_BLINK = 5,
    RAPID_BLINK = 6,
    REVERSE = 7,
};

enum class ConsoleForeground
{
    DEFAULT = 39,
    BLACK = 30,
    DARK_RED = 31,
    DARK_GREEN = 32,
    DARK_YELLOW = 33,
    DARK_BLUE = 34,
    DARK_MAGENTA = 35,
    DARK_CYAN = 36,
    GRAY = 37,
    DARK_GRAY = 90,
    RED = 91,
    GREEN = 92,
    YELLOW = 93,
    BLUE = 94,
    MAGENTA = 95,
    CYAN = 96,
    WHITE = 97
};

enum class ConsoleBackground
{
    DEFAULT = 49,
    BLACK = 40,
    DARK_RED = 41,
    DARK_GREEN = 42,
    DARK_YELLOW = 43,
    DARK_BLUE = 44,
    DARK_MAGENTA = 45,
    DARK_CYAN = 46,
    GRAY = 47,
    DARK_GRAY = 100,
    RED = 101,
    GREEN = 102,
    YELLOW = 103,
    BLUE = 104,
    MAGENTA = 105,
    CYAN = 106,
    WHITE = 107
};

class Console
{
private:
    static void EnableVirtualTermimalProcessing()
    {
#if defined WINDOWS_PLATFORM
        HANDLE hOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
        DWORD dwMode = 0;
        GetConsoleMode(hOut, &dwMode);
        if (!(dwMode & ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING))
        {
            dwMode |= ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING;
            SetConsoleMode(hOut, dwMode);
        }
#endif
    }

    static void ResetTerminalFormat()
    {
        std::cout << u8"\033[0m";
    }

    static void SetVirtualTerminalFormat(ConsoleForeground foreground, ConsoleBackground background, std::set<ConsoleTextStyle> styles)
    {
        String format = u8"\033[";
        format.append(std::to_string(static_cast<int>(foreground)));
        format.append(u8";");
        format.append(std::to_string(static_cast<int>(background)));
        if (styles.size() > 0)
        {
            for (auto it = styles.begin(); it != styles.end(); ++it)
            {
                format.append(u8";");
                format.append(std::to_string(static_cast<int>(*it)));
            }
        }
        format.append(u8"m");
        std::cout << format;
    }
public:
    static void Clear()
    {

#ifdef WINDOWS_PLATFORM
        std::system(u8"cls");
#elif LINUX_PLATFORM || defined MACOS_PLATFORM
        std::system(u8"clear");
#elif EMSCRIPTEN_PLATFORM
        emscripten::val::global()["console"].call<void>(u8"clear");
#else
        static_assert(false, "Unknown Platform");
#endif
    }

    static void Write(const String& s, ConsoleForeground foreground = ConsoleForeground::DEFAULT, ConsoleBackground background = ConsoleBackground::DEFAULT, std::set<ConsoleTextStyle> styles = {})
    {
#ifndef EMSCRIPTEN_PLATFORM
        EnableVirtualTermimalProcessing();
        SetVirtualTerminalFormat(foreground, background, styles);
#endif
        String str = s;
#ifdef WINDOWS_PLATFORM
        WString unicode = Strings::StringToWideString(str);
        WriteConsole(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), unicode.c_str(), static_cast<DWORD>(unicode.length()), nullptr, nullptr);
#elif defined LINUX_PLATFORM || defined MACOS_PLATFORM || EMSCRIPTEN_PLATFORM
        std::cout << str;
#else
        static_assert(false, "Unknown Platform");
#endif

#ifndef EMSCRIPTEN_PLATFORM
        ResetTerminalFormat();
#endif
    }

    static void WriteLine(const String& s, ConsoleForeground foreground = ConsoleForeground::DEFAULT, ConsoleBackground background = ConsoleBackground::DEFAULT, std::set<ConsoleTextStyle> styles = {})
    {
        Write(s, foreground, background, styles);
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    static void Write(const WString& s, ConsoleForeground foreground = ConsoleForeground::DEFAULT, ConsoleBackground background = ConsoleBackground::DEFAULT, std::set<ConsoleTextStyle> styles = {})
    {
#ifndef EMSCRIPTEN_PLATFORM
        EnableVirtualTermimalProcessing();
        SetVirtualTerminalFormat(foreground, background, styles);
#endif
        WString str = s;

#ifdef WINDOWS_PLATFORM
        WriteConsole(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), str.c_str(), static_cast<DWORD>(str.length()), nullptr, nullptr);
#elif LINUX_PLATFORM || MACOS_PLATFORM || EMSCRIPTEN_PLATFORM
        std::cout << Strings::WideStringToString(str);
#else
        static_assert(false, "Unknown Platform");
#endif

#ifndef EMSCRIPTEN_PLATFORM
        ResetTerminalFormat();
#endif
    }

    static void WriteLine(const WString& s, ConsoleForeground foreground = ConsoleForeground::DEFAULT, ConsoleBackground background = ConsoleBackground::DEFAULT, std::set<ConsoleTextStyle> styles = {})
    {
        Write(s, foreground, background, styles);
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    static void WriteLine()
    {
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    static void Pause()
    {
        char c;
        do
        {
            c = getchar();
            std::cout << "Press Key " << std::endl;
        } while (c != 64);
        std::cout << "KeyPressed" << std::endl;
    }

    static int PauseAny(bool printWhenPressed = false, ConsoleForeground foreground = ConsoleForeground::DEFAULT, ConsoleBackground background = ConsoleBackground::DEFAULT, std::set<ConsoleTextStyle> styles = {})
    {
        int ch;
#ifdef WINDOWS_PLATFORM
        ch = _getch();
#elif LINUX_PLATFORM || MACOS_PLATFORM || EMSCRIPTEN_PLATFORM
        struct termios oldt, newt;
        tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &oldt);
        newt = oldt;
        newt.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO);
        tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &newt);
        ch = getchar();
        tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &oldt);
#else
        static_assert(false, "Unknown Platform");
#endif
        if (printWhenPressed)
        {
            Console::Write(String(1, ch), foreground, background, styles);
        }
        return ch;
    }
};



int main()
{
    std::locale::global(std::locale(u8"en_US.UTF-8"));
    String dataStr = u8"Zoë Saldaña played in La maldición del padre Cardona. ëèñ αω óóChloë";
    WString dataWStr = L"Zoë Saldaña played in La maldición del padre Cardona. ëèñ αω óóChloë";
    std::string locale = u8"";
    //std::string locale = u8"de_DE.UTF-8";
    //std::string locale = u8"en_US.UTF-8";
    Console::WriteLine(dataStr);
    Console::WriteLine(dataWStr);
    dataStr = Strings::ToUpper(dataStr);
    dataWStr = Strings::ToUpper(dataWStr);
    Console::WriteLine(dataStr);
    Console::WriteLine(dataWStr);
    dataStr = Strings::ToLower(dataStr);
    dataWStr = Strings::ToLower(dataWStr);
    Console::WriteLine(dataStr);
    Console::WriteLine(dataWStr);
    
    
    Console::WriteLine(u8"Press any key to exit"s, ConsoleForeground::DARK_GRAY);
    Console::PauseAny();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to convert a std::wstring (unicode string) to upper case in C++. This code also handles the case where the locale "en_US.UTF8" is not available by falling back to the default locale. Here is no change of the default locale, so other parts of the software which use the global one won't be affected.

```
#include <locale>
#include <string>

std::locale CreateLocale() 
{
    try {
        return std::locale("en_US.UTF8"); // some OS may not support this locale
    }
    catch (const std::runtime_error&) {
        return std::locale(); // fallback to the default locale
    }
}

// Lazy initialize facet
const std::ctype<wchar_t>& FacetUtf8() {
    static const std::locale localeUtf8(CreateLocale());
    static const std::ctype<wchar_t>& facet = std::use_facet<std::ctype<wchar_t> >(localeUtf8);
    return facet;
}
    
void MakeUpper(std::wstring& str)
{   
    FacetUtf8().toupper(&str[0], &str[str.size()]);
}

void MakeLower(std::wstring& str)
{
    FacetUtf8().tolower(&str[0], &str[str.size()]);
}
```

Here's an example of how to use it:

```
std::wstring str = L"hello, world! áăắặẳẵ";
MakeUpper(str);
wcout << str;  // Outputs: "HELLO, WORLD! ÁĂẮẶẲẴ"
```