# C++ Static array

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio-2010, dictionary, static

I would like to create a custom lower / upper case function for wstrings.

Therefore I am using a map of integers.

Currently I am automatically creating a function from these maps:

```
(...)
else if (iCharCode==65)
{
    iRet=97;
}
else if (iCharCode==66)
{
    iRet=98;
}
else if (iCharCode==67)
{
    iRet=99;
}
else if (iCharCode==68)
{
    iRet=100;
}
else if (iCharCode==69)
{
    iRet=101;
}
else if (iCharCode==70)
{
    iRet=102;
}
else if (iCharCode==42818)
{
    iRet=42819;
}
(...)
```

However, the function is going to be pretty large if I turn my map into a if-statement like this.

I would therefore like a use a real map instead, but I don't want to load it at runtime. 
I would prefer having a static map, but I am not sure how to do that.

Can somebody share his thoughts?

Comment: That was just a coincidence. Most of the times it is not +32.

Comment: You may want to take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11491/string-to-lower-upper-in-c

Comment: @Dweeberly Not working for non-ASCII chars, therefore I am doing my own function.

Comment: @Jimmy Can you delete your comment? You got so many upvotes that it is misleading.

Comment: A `std::map<int,int>` would use far too much memory. One approach is to create an array for the easy values, for example, an array of 256 `int` case-mapped values for the first 256 values, and a function for the rest. In general, a function can be much more compact than the code here; for example, `if(65 <= iCharCode && iCharCode < 71) iRet = iCharCode + 32; else ...`.

Comment: ok - i'll delete it (not often I have to delete something because it gets so many upvotes ;-) have you considered using a unicode library http://userguide.icu-project.org/transforms/casemappings

Comment: The link I posted contained info on unicode conversions.  Are you trying to do codepage conversions?  Transcoding is hard and it's generally saver to find a well tested library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the following code can help:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>

std::map<int, int> code_map = {
  {65, 97},
  {66, 98},
  {67, 99},
  {68, 100},
  {69, 101},
  {70, 102},  
};


int main() {
  for(const auto & pair : code_map) {
    std::cout<<pair.first<<" maps to "<<pair.second<<std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Compiling with `g++ example.cpp -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra` (OS X 10.7.4 GCC 4.8.1) yields:

```
$ ./a.out 
65 maps to 97
66 maps to 98
67 maps to 99
68 maps to 100
69 maps to 101
70 maps to 102
```

Comment: But I think the map is created anew each time I initiate code_map, right?

Comment: `code_map` is only constructed once -- when the program is started.

Comment: I am getting the error "Initialization using {...} is not valid for type map<int,int>".

Comment: @tmighty: That style of initialisation is only valid in C++11. If you're stuck in the past, you'll need to write a function to initialise it, or use something like Boost.Assignment. Alternatively, use a sorted array of `pair<int,int>` rather than a map, with a binary search for lookup. That's perhaps more efficient, and can be initialised statically.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I have updated from VS2010 to VS2012 now, but the IDE tells me the same error.

Comment: The exact error is: IntelliSense: Initialization with "{...}" invalid for object of type ""std::map<int, int, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, int>>>""

Answer (score 0):

You could implement the map as a sorted array of pairs. This can be initialised statically. Look up a value using a binary search, e.g. `std::lower_bound` with a comparator comparing the first element of each pair.

As further optimisation, you might consider mapping ranges rather than individual characters, using an array of (range_begin, range_end, offset) triplets. This would reduce the whole ASCII alphabet to a single entry; but might be less effective for other alphabets.